# Qual a forma correta de usar BCrypt?

Tags: c#, bcrypt

Estou querendo dar um nível satisfatório de segurança ao meu sistema. Em minhas pesquisas encontrei várias funções que criam hashs para senhas, mas dentre todas elas, pelo que vi as mais recomendadas foram PBKDF2 e BCrypt.

Em todas as pesquisas no entanto, o que mais vi foi: "Se mal utilizada, uma hash não serve de nada!".

> Então aí vai a pergunta, qual a maneira correta de criar uma hash
>   usando BCrypt, por exemplo?

Segue meu código como está atualmente:

```
public static string HashGeneration(string password)
{
      // Configurations
      int workfactor = 10; // 2 ^ (10) = 1024 iterations.

      string salt = BCrypt.Net.BCrypt.GenerateSalt(workfactor);
      string hash = BCrypt.Net.BCrypt.HashPassword(password, salt);

      return hash;
}

public static bool PasswordCompare(string hash, string password)
{
      return BCrypt.Net.BCrypt.Verify(password, hash);
}
```

Comment: Parece correta pra mim... Não sei se um fator de trabalho 10 é bom o bastante (tal como [no caso do PBKDF2](http://security.stackexchange.com/q/3959/6939), [também pro bcrypt você deve usar o maior fator tolerável](http://security.stackexchange.com/q/17207/6939)), mas de resto está tudo bem (você está criando um sal aleatório, a saída do bcrypt já inclui o sal e o fator de trabalho, e a verificação da senha está ok). P.S. Para 2015, [essa resposta no security.SE](http://security.stackexchange.com/a/83382/6939) sugere um fator de trabalho de `16` (mas se seu sistema suportar mais, melhor).

Comment: @mgibsonbr eu sei porque você está evitando responder mas duvido que alguém vá responder melhor, vá em frente! E se alguém responder, a sua não causará problema, até porque você certamente colocará um aviso que você não dá garantias que viu tudo o que pode estar errado e nem conhece esta implementação específica, não viu outras partes da aplicação, etc.

Comment: @bigown Sinceramente, isso não me ocorreu... :P Na minha concepção, *para o propósito de armazenar senhas* não faz muita diferença se há ou não falha na implementação, se o resultado estiver correto o trabalho do atacante será o mesmo. Depois de ler seu comentário eu até pensei "e se uma implementação ruim permitir um *timing attack*?" mas logo descartei, pois tal como na [sua pergunta original](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/2402/215), o hash coloca um limite inferior ao teste de uma senha, então mesmo um ataque de força bruta no servidor nunca será mais rápido que o ataque offline.

Comment: @bigown Eu já deveria ter aprendido a essas alturas a não fazer esse tipo de afirmação... De fato, eu continuo sem conhecer nenhum *timing attack* aplicável ao hash de senhas, mas me lembrei de [já ter estudado sobre](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DgZwQU0U6vI) um cenário bastante semelhante - verificação de MACs - em que de fato um defeito na implementação permite um ataque remoto que completamente destrói a segurança. Não se aplica aqui (pois lá fixava-se a mensagem e variava o MAC, aqui fixa-se o hash e varia a senha) mas serve de alerta que as coisas nunca são tão simples como parecem...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seu código me parece correto. Não conheço essa biblioteca específica (estranhei que o `workFactor` era usado como parâmetro do `GenerateSalt`, e não do `HashPassword`, mas [aparentemente é assim mesmo](https://code.google.com/p/bcryptnet/)), nem sei se a qualidade da sua implementação é satisfatória (muita gente parece a usar, entretanto, então suponho que o nível de escrutínio que ela recebeu seja ok), mas não enxergo qualquer problema em potencial nesse cenário de uso.

Como muitas outras, essa biblioteca já te ajuda guardando o sal e o fator de trabalho na saída do hash (acho que é `$sal$fator$hash`, ou talvez `$versão$fator$sal+hash`, ou algo assim), de modo que basta usar a saída do `HashPassword` no `Verify` que a biblioteca cuida dos detalhes.

Quanto ao melhor valor pra se usar como fator de trabalho, a mesma recomendação da [minha outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/87128/215) continua valendo: use o maior valor que seja "tolerável" na sua aplicação. Estabeleça um "alvo" pra quanto tempo a verificação do hash deva demorar a cada login, e ajuste o fator de trabalho de modo que ele leve aproximadamente esse tempo. [Essa resposta no security.SE](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/83382/6939) faz um cálculo interessante - levando a data atual em consideração ao determinar o fator de trabalho (para 2015, um fator de `16` é sugerido) - mas não existe resposta absoluta quanto a isso. Tenha apenas em mente que, quanto maior o fator, mais difícil será para o atacante adivinhar a senha:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

(e como se vê na tabela acima, uma senha fraca está além da salvação por qualquer hash, então certifique-se que as senhas - em especial do admin - possuam parâmetros mínimos de segurança)