# PHP não consegue ler POST enviado por JavaScript

Tags: php, javascript, html

Estou criando um sistema de login para meu site seguindo [este tutorial](http://pt.wikihow.com/Criar-um-Script-de-Login-Seguro-em-PHP-e-MySQL), mas estou com um problema na hora de realizar o login. Aparentemente, o código em JavaScript não realiza a passagem dos parâmetros do formulário corretamente. O código da página de login é:

```js
function hex_sha512(value) {
    // apenas para simular
    return 'hashed-value';
}

function formhash(form, password) {
    // Crie um novo elemento de input, o qual será o campo para a senha com hash. 
    var p = document.createElement("input");

    // Adicione um novo elemento ao nosso formulário. 
    form.appendChild(p);
    p.name = "p";
    p.type = "hidden";
    p.value = hex_sha512(password.value);

    // Cuidado para não deixar que a senha em texto simples não seja enviada. 
    password.value = "";

    // Finalmente, envie o formulário.
    form.submit();
}
```

```html
<form action="includes/process_login.php" method="POST" name="login_form">
  <div class="form-group">
    <input class="form-control" placeholder="E-mail" name="email" type="email" autofocus>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <input class="form-control" placeholder="Password" name="password" type="password" value="" id="password">
  </div>
  <div class="checkbox">
    <label>
      <input name="remember" type="checkbox" value="Remember Me">Remember Me
    </label>
  </div>
  <!-- Você também pode alterar este botão para um input como opção de envio -->
  <input type="button" value="Login" onclick="formhash(this.form, this.form.password, this.form.p);" class="btn btn-lg btn-success btn-block"/>
</form>
```

Por algum motivo, quando eu testo, na página **process_login.php**, se as variáveis `$_POST['email']` e `$POST['p']` estão setadas, ele retorna falso, como se elas não estivessem setadas.

**process_login.php**:

```
    if (isset($_POST['email'], $_POST['p'])) {
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $password = $_POST['p'];

    if (login($email, $password, $mysqli) == true) {
        // Login com sucesso
    } else {
        // Falha de login 
    }
} else {
    // As variáveis POST corretas não foram enviadas para esta página. 
    echo 'Invalid Request';
}
```

O sistema sempre cai no "Invalid Request".

O que poderia ser?

Comment: O `this` se refere ao elemente atual, no apenas submit.

Comment: Mas quando eu faço um alert(form.name) ou alert(password.value) ele retorna os valores corretamente.

Comment: Isso porque o `form` é referência geral.

Comment: Não há nenhum problema nos códigos que apresentou. O que quer dizer com "javascript não envia corretamente"? Por acaso está tentando resgatar `$_POST['password']`? Se for o caso, está errado pois deve invocar `$_POST['p']`, o qual contém o password encriptado. Essa é a ideia do tutorial.

Comment: o código está correto, parece que o problema é um erro de digitação: `$POST['p']` deveria ser `$_POST['p']` (faltou um "_")

Comment: Na código da página está correto. Só na hora de escrever ali que esqueco o "_". Adicionei o código à pergunta para vocês avaliarem. Muito obrigado!

Comment: se no código está correto, então não deveria dar problema... para tirar dúvidas, dê um print_r em $POST..

Answer (score -1):

Você precisa usar JavaScript? Se não precisa, pode fazer o seguinte:

#### Página de login

```
<form action="includes/process_login.php" method="POST">
    <div class="form-group">
            <input class="form-control" placeholder="E-mail" name="email" type="email" autofocus>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
            <input class="form-control" placeholder="Password" name="password" type="password" value="" id="password">
    </div>
    <div class="checkbox">
      <label>
         <input name="remember" type="checkbox" value="Remember Me">Remember Me
     </label>
    </div>
     <!-- Você também pode alterar este botão para um input como opção de envio -->
     <button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-success btn-block"/>Login</button>
</form>
```

#### Página: process_login.php

```
<?php
$email = $_POST['email'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
?>
```

Dessa forma, você está submetendo o form com o método POST, e recebendo os inputs do form na outra página com o mesmo método.

Utilizo dessa forma pois ainda não domino muito as funções do JS e acredito que possa atender suas necessidades.

Só lembrando que dessa forma não há nenhum hash, mas aparentemente você já está sabendo fazer. Caso precise de mais algum material, segue: [Como fazer hash de senhas de forma segura?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/2402/como-fazer-hash-de-senhas-de-forma-segura?rq=1)

Comment: Eu uso o JS para fazer o hash da senha, por isso preciso dele.