# como descriptografar md5 e sha1?

Tags: php, md5, sha1

bom gostaria de saber como descriptografar o `md5` e o `sha 1` estou usando os dois para inserir a senha do usuário no banco, porem tenho que fazer uma pagina para quem esqueceu a senha e se eu somente jogar o valor que ta no banco ele vai manda a criptografia inteira intao eu queria saber se e possível algo como a senha for `12345` e a criptografia for `aBvc34ddsa` na hora que o usuário digitar o e-mail dele cadastrado ele pegar a senha que esta naquele campo e descriptografa mandando para o usuário a senha `12345` e nao `aBvc34ddsa` teria como fazer isso?

Comment: blz intao quer dizer que se eu pegar o valor do banco pra enviar para o usuario ele vai me trazer a senha correta?

Comment: MD5 é hash de mão unica, você cria não tem como voltar entendeu.

Comment: E ambos não são criptografia, são apenas hashes. Aliás, a única vantagem de hash pra senha é não ter volta. Ninguém precisaria disso numa aplicação normal. Sugestão de leitura: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/2402/ - No seu caso, basta mandar um link pra pessoa fazer nova senha, e ao fazer, sobreescreve a velha.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tanto o MD5 quanto o SHA1 são criptografias que não são possíveis de descriptografar.
A forma correta de utilizar é:

Quando algo é criptografado em md5 ou sha1 ele vai gerar um HASH de 128 bit e geralmente vai ter 32 digitos hexadecimais. Toda vez que a mesma palavra for criptografada em md5 vai gerar o mesmo hash.

A ultilização mais comum dessa forma de criptografia é somente para verificar a integridade do dado, por exemplo, as vezes você vai baixar algum arquivo e eles fornecem o código fonte e um "checksum" do código, esse checksum você pode gerar um md5 do código que vc baixou e comparar com o fornecido pelo fabricante, se baterem você pode considerar que o código não foi alterado e o aplicativo não tem nenhum virus dentro dele.
É comum utilizar para senhas, por exemplo, você não precisa saber a senha do seu usuario, nem é uma boa pratica armazena-la no banco, como posso validar um usuario dessa forma?
Você armazena o hash do md5 no banco, e quando o usuario tentar logar você pega a senha que ele forneceu encripta ela em md5 e compara, se bater elas são iguais, você acabou de validar uma senha sem saber qual é a senha de fato.

Já o sha1 é praticamente a mesma coisa, a diferença é que ele gera um HASG de 160bit e pode gerar um hexadecimal de 40 digitos.

Abraços

Comment: -1 pelo "criptografia"

Comment: Tem uns probleminhas na resposta: 1) MD5 e SHA não são criptografia 2) integridade / checksum normalmente usam CRC e similares, que são algoritmos mais rápidos e com objetivos e requisitos diferentes de MD5 e SHA. 3) Você não deve armazenar o MD5 ou SHA direto no banco, pois não é seguro. No mínimo precisa fazer um salt.

Comment: Vejo tanto resposta e pergunta bem nada a vê ai, n tem 1 para dar votedown. Fiquem a vontade para contribuir e editar a resposta.