# password_hash ou crypt, qual traz mais segurança?

Tags: php, hash

Eu não sei muito de `hash` e segurança, encontrei duas funções funcionais e não descobri qual seria a diferença entre elas e consequentemente qual a mais segura para salvar e capturar senhas.

Minha dúvida é qual devo usar, `password_hash` ou `crypt`? Sei que o `password_hash` usa internamente o `crypt`, isso o deixa mais completo e seguro?

> Exemplos:

**cript:**

```
$hash = crypt($pass); //criptografa
if(crypt($pass, $hash) == $hash) //verifica a senha
```

**password_hash**

```
$options = [
    'cost' => 11,
    'salt' => mcrypt_create_iv(50, MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM),
];

$hash = password_hash($pass, PASSWORD_BCRYPT, $options); //criptografa
if (password_verify($pass, $hash)) //verifica senha
```

Comment: **Relacionado:** [Como fazer hash de senhas de forma segura?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/2402/3635)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O jeito mais simples de explicar a diferença existente, é dizer que ambos possuem padrões diferentes, e um permite mais algoritmos que outro, que em algumas vezes podem variar consoante o sistema em uso, isso para o `crypt`.

O método `crypt` usa **salt** como parâmetro opcional em versões menores do `PHP` o que resulta em passwords mais fracas, e em versões mais recentes do `PHP` retorna um *E_NOTICE* caso não lhe seja fornecido um salt.
O método `crypt` utiliza o algoritmo `DES` como padrão, ou até mesmo o `MD5` isso dependendo o sistema em uso, e suporta também vários algoritmos de encriptação.

Com o método `password_hash`, pode-se utilizar apenas um algoritmo, que é o `bcrypt`, ou o padrão caso queiramos que quando um novo algoritmo mais seguro que o anterior for posto em funcionamento possamos também usa-lo.

Em versões recentes do `PHP` recomenda-se não criar **salts** manualmente, à menos que seja realmente necessário, pois a função `password_hash` já cria salts suficientemente seguros.

O método `password_hash` é basicamente uma derivada do método `crypt`, sendo que ambos os métodos são compatíveis.

O `crypt` foi vagamente usado por muitos usuários antes da chegada do `password_hash` com o `PHP >= 5.5.0` que permitiu aos usuários focar a criação da hash em um algoritmo específico testado, ainda hoje muita gente usa o `crypt` em vez do `password_hash`.

Nenhum é menos seguro que outro, diferem apenas no modo como são empregados.