# Como validar senha md5 com banco de dados?

Tags: php, md5

No banco de dados já está criptografado com `md5`, quando a tento logar-me usando:

```
email: joao@email.com |
senha: 123456 
**ACESSO NEGADO**
```

e

```
email: joao@email.com |
senha: criptografada md5
**ACESSO LIBERADO**
```

Segue o código

```
<?php include('conecta.php');
mysql_select_db(guara423_gestao) or die('Erro conexão com o banco');
session_start();
?>

<html>

<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
</head>
<script>
    function loginsuccessfuly(){
        setTimeout("window.location='index.php'", 1000);
    }
    function loginfailed(){
        setTimeout("window.location='login.php'", 1000);
    }
</script>

</html>
<?php
$email = $_POST['email'];
$senha = $_POST['senha'];
$scodif = md5($senha);

$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM user WHERE email = '$email' and senha = '$scodif'");
$row = mysql_num_rows($sql);

if ($row > 0){
    $_SESSION['email']=$_POST['email'];
    $_SESSION['senha']=$_POST["senha"];
    echo "Logado com Sucesso. Redirecionando...";
    echo "<script>loginsuccessfuly()</script>";
}else{
    echo "Nome de usuário ou senha inválidos.";
    echo "<script>loginfailed()</script>";
}
?>
```

Comment: Qual é a dúvida no código? Você já está verificando se existe o usuario com email e a senha com md5...

Comment: Parece não existir erro na comparação. Talvez o problema seja no momento de gravar na variável de sessão: `$_SESSION['senha']=$_POST["senha"];`. Não seria `$_SESSION['senha']=$scodif` ? De qualquer forma, não está claro qual ou onde está realmente a dificuldade.

Comment: Quando você *cadastrou* o usuário você não teria por acaso feito o MD5 duas vezes? Pois se ele aceita `md5(senha)`, então o que está salvo no BD é `md5(md5(senha))`. P.S. Não use MD5 pra proteger senhas, ver [essa outra pergunta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/2402/215) para mais detalhes.

Comment: Fica a sugestão de repensar nessa sua proteção de senha, pois o MD5 só dá uma escondidinha boba nela. MD5 (ainda mais sem salt) não é proteção de senha, e atualmente é muito fácil reverter o MD5 na maioria dos casos.

Answer (score 1):

Na inclusão eu já realizaria a criptografia, como o wordpress já faz. O MySQL já possui a função e portanto a sua inclusão poderia ser:

```
"INSERT INTO user (email,senha) values (:email, MD5(:senha))"
```

no teste você poderia usar a função diretamente:

```
"SELECT email,senha FROM user WHERE email = :email and senha = MD5(:senha)"
```