# Encriptação da senha do WordPress muda quando se faz Login

Tags: php, wordpress

Bom eu desenvolvi um website em localhost com o objectivo de conectar a uma base de dados do WordPress. Fui pesquisar um pouco mais sobre a encriptação que o WordPress utilizava e acabei por perceber que precisava do ficheiro `class-phpass.php` para encriptar a senha e depois comparar com a que o utilizador inseriu. Para esse efeito utilizei o seguinte código:

```
include_once ('passwordHash.php'); //Buscar o ficheiro class-phpass.php ( Nome alterado )
$hash= new PasswordHash( 8, true );

$user_login = $_POST['username']; //Buscar o Username que o utilizador inseriu no Login
$user_pass = $hash->HashPassword($_POST['password']); //Buscar a password e encripta-la

include_once('DataAccess.php');
$db = new DataAccess();
$stored_hash = $db->getPassword(); //Buscar todas as password dos utilizadores
$correta = $hash->CheckPassword( $user_pass, $stored_hash ); //Comparar as passwords

if ($correta == true){ ... } //Se existir alguém com a mesma password verifica se corresponde ao Username.
```

O problema disto tudo é que sempre que o utilizador faz Login, o ficheiro `passwordHash.php` retorna uma encriptação da password de maneira diferente da que está na base de dados.

**Por exemplo:** A password de um utilizador quando se regista é abc e fica guardada assim: `$P$BbRyz9JuNQ6NWQ0.wYR82HZhqlcJXD.` quando o utilizador se vai logar e insere a mesma password ela já encripta assim: `$P$Bon4zeRrOOcZMmafO09.J1U/Fs5Qgr1` e o objetivo é que encripte da mesma maneira e devolva `$P$BbRyz9JuNQ6NWQ0.wYR82HZhqlcJXD.` para que o utilizador se consiga logar.

Comment: Bom, como você já deletou [a que eu reabri](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/111895/), vou deixar apenas o comentário de novo: Já expliquei mais de uma vez que o hash é pra mudar mesmo, e já indiquei a resposta que tem a explicação. Quanto ao seu código, não bate com seu texto. Sugeriria melhorar a descrição do problema pra bater com o código. Se precisar da explicação de novo, segue o link: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/4837/70

Comment: Eu não sei como me fazer explicar melhor...

Comment: Bom, deixemos como está, vamos torcer pra alguém conseguir resolver. Se você conseguir entender que é normal mudar, já ajuda. Quando uma senha é gerada pelo PasswordHash ela vai com o hash junto, e o CheckPassword sabe fazer a checagem corretamente. Tem que ver se seu DB está correto também (tamanho dos campos etc). Como na outra pergunta você disse que migrou DB, pode estar aí o problema.

Comment: Qual o retorno da função `$db->getPassword()`? Você diz estar buscando todas senhas dos utilizadores, está retornando um array então? Você não pode passar um array e uma string para `CheckPassword`, você deve passar 2 hashes.

Comment: @Marco Aurélio Deleu Dá esse código aqui: `object(mysqli_result)#4 (5) { ["current_field"]=> int(0) ["field_count"]=> int(1) ["lengths"]=> NULL ["num_rows"]=> int(14) ["type"]=> int(0) }`

Comment: @Bacco Eu não migrei a base de dados. Eu apenas construí, digamos, uma nova página para aquela base de dados e acrescentei algumas colunas. Permitindo assim os utilizadores registarem-se em uma página diferente e usar aquela apenas para fazer login e consultar os seus equipamentos.

Comment: Bruny a parte das senhas no DB é nova? Deixou espaço suficiente no campo? Note que o erro pode estar na leitura do DB, como o @MarcoAurélioDeleu comentou.

Comment: Tá em varchar 255. Tem mais do que espaço.

Comment: Imprima o retorno do DB na tela pra ter certeza que está recuperando certo.

Comment: seu problema está exatamente na variável `$stored_hash`. Ao invés de passa-lá dessa forma ao checkPassword, certifique-se de obter apenas um valor da coluna password filtrando por login.

Comment: @MarcoAurélioDeleu Ahhh... Agora faz sentido. E como é que eu consigo a password apenas da pessoa que se está a tentar logar? Necessito de comparar o Username para ver se tem algum na base de dados e se existir encripto a senha e depois faço a validação da password?

Comment: Isso. use a variável `$user_login` para fazer um `SELECT` do tipo `SELECT * FROM wp_users WHERE campo_usuario = $user_login`. Verifique se a query retorna resultado. Se sim, significa que o usuário existe. Obtenha toda a linha do registro (contendo todas as colunas). Em seguinda, encrypte a senha enviada via POST e em seguida compare as duas pela função checkPassword.

Comment: Não encripta a senha, passe ela sem encriptar para a função checkpassword. A checkpassword pega automaticamente o hash da senha encriptada, e aplica na senha limpa, pra encriptar igual. `CheckPassword( $senha_em_plaintext, $hash_que_veio_do_db  )`

Comment: Ele está a devolver isto da function: `object(mysqli_result)#3 (5) { ["current_field"]=> int(0) ["field_count"]=> int(1) ["lengths"]=> NULL ["num_rows"]=> int(1) ["type"]=> int(0) }
` mas apenas usei o `select (user_pass)
     from wp_users 
     where user_login = '$user_login'`

Comment: @MarcoAurélioDeleu Continua sem encriptar a password

Answer (score -2):

Bom dia,

A solução é:

Nº 1: Pegue somente o campo senha do usuário em questão no banco, exemplo: $sql = "SELECT user_pass FROM wp_users where user_login = 'login_digitado_na_tela'";

Nº 2:  inclua o 'class-phpass.php'

Nº 3: instancie ele >> $hash= new PasswordHash( 8, true );

Nº 4: Passe somente as duas strings que deseja checar: >> $correta = $hash->CheckPassword( $password_form_tela, $password_buscado_no_banco);

Explicação: $hash->CheckPassword( string, string);

Ao término faça o If.