# Como utilizar Salt corretamente com MD5

Tags: java, criptografia

Estou utilizando [Apache Commons Codec](http://Apache%20Commons%20Codec) para encriptar as senhas dos usuários do sistema. Ex:

```
DigestUtils.md5Hex(usuario.getSenha())
```

O problema é que dependendo da senha ela pode ser facilmente quebrada, então pensei em criar uma String complexa e sempre adiciona-la no final de cada senha criada

```
String salt = "3&1cNM!+<c#KtPzx*";
DigestUtils.md5Hex(usuario.getSenha()+salt)
```

Dessa forma todas as senhas criadas iriam ter essa String concatenada. Minha dúvida são as seguintes:

- Isso realmente dificultaria a quebra dessas senhas?
- Qual seriam os passos de gerar esse salt dinamicamente? Isso
  funcionaria?

Comment: Relacionada: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/2402/101

Comment: Opa, obrigado @bigown não tinha achado, erro meu.