# Protegendo dados em memória

Tags: c#, .net, string, segurança, memória

Fiz uma leitura de vários artigos sobre criptografia etc... A criptografia relatada pelos *posts* foi um sucesso no meu programa, no entanto alguns dados ficam na memória estando vulneráveis a leitores Assembly em tempo real. Um exemplo disso é **Cheat Engine**, que uso para verificar a segurança da minha aplicação em memória. Veja no exemplo abaixo um exemplo do código que usei:

```
//A string desprotegida
string strCriptografar = "stringParaCriptografar";

//Classe que uso para criptografar
Cript criptClasse = new Cript();
//Aqui criptografo o valor da string...
string textoCriptografado = cript.Criptografar(strCriptografar, "mykey");
```

Por meio disso consigo criptografar o valor da *string*, mas quando analiso no *disassembly* a *string* com o texto continua na memória no momento da execução. Poderiam me ajudar?

Comment: E o que você pretende? Retirar o conteúdo da memoria assim que criptografar?

Comment: Quando criptografo o valor de "strCriptografar" continua na memória, visível.

Comment: O problema eu entendi, estou tentando entender se você precisa manter a variável original ou se pode guardar somente o criptografado.

Comment: Esse valor eu preciso dele, quero guardar informações de sessão para que não possam ser acessados como você viu os disassemblers. Essas informações devem ficar em memória, sendo necessárias para a aplicacação. Desculpe se não estou explicando de forma apropriada...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Como já foi dito, uma questão sobre segurança raramente é simples**. Porém, se você precisa ter os dados em memória, sem que eles sejam visíveis, não use nenhuma variável temporária/fixa para armazenamento antes da criptografia.

De cara, isso envolve um problema um pouco mais específico que é o modo como o gerenciamento de memória é feito no .NET. Então, se você usa uma variável string, ela ficara armazenada até que o GC decida que não é mais util e você não tem controle sobre quando será desalocada.

Existem diversos artigos sobre isso, tente esse:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/38069/Memory-Management-in-NET

Além disso, porque você precisa iniciar a string em uma variável com texto plano? Se vai usar, você poderia ao menos usar ela em uma **SecureString**, veja esse link:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.security.securestring(v=vs.110).aspx

Mas, ai também envolve o quanto uma SecureString é segura :)

O problema maior está na forma como você capta a string e como sua criptografia funciona. Mas, em algum momento, ela passará pela memória para poder ser criptografada.

Você poderia usar código não gerenciado, para controlar melhor o tempo que ela permanece na memória, mas, codigo não gerenciado possui outros problemas de segurança, muitos deles vinculados ao gerenciamento da memória ou fluxo de execução do programa.

Não existe bala de prata. Mesmo um char, digitado no teclado, tem que passar por um buffer, apenas tente garantir que o local onde você coloca o texto plano, existe no menor tempo possível e nunca está guardado em um escopo de longa duração.

Veja a diferença no exemplo de código do link para SecureString:

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Security;

public class Example
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        // Instantiate the secure string.
        SecureString securePwd = new SecureString();
        ConsoleKeyInfo key;

        Console.Write("Enter password: ");
        do {
           key = Console.ReadKey(true);

           // Ignore any key out of range.
           if (((int) key.Key) >= 65 && ((int) key.Key <= 90)) {
              // Append the character to the password.
              securePwd.AppendChar(key.KeyChar);
              Console.Write("*");
           }   
        // Exit if Enter key is pressed.
        } while (key.Key != ConsoleKey.Enter);
        Console.WriteLine();

        try {
            Process.Start("Notepad.exe", "MyUser", securePwd, "MYDOMAIN");
        }
        catch (Win32Exception e) {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }
        finally {
           securePwd.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

A principal diferença é que ele não guarda uma string em texto plano para depois passar para a criptografia, ele já adiciona char a char a string criptografada.

Outra coisa que ele faz, é que ele sobrescreve cada char a cada novo char digitado, assim, so a SecureString contem em memória a sequencia toda, mas, o char atual continua em memória pelo tempo que o o escopo e o GC permitirem.

Esse caso particular de análise, a primeira vista, parece só servir para uma entrada char a char pelo console, porém, você deve lembrar que o mesmo pode ser aplicado ao fluxo de leitura de uma Stream qualquer byte-a-byte, não esquecendo é claro dos buffers ocultos na implementação da maioria das APIs padrão.

Além disso, se a máquina está comprometida, mesmo essa abordagem cai facilmente sobre um Keylogger. :(

Answer (score 5):

A única ajuda que podemos dar é não manter a senha em lugar algum. Não existe milagre.

Se precisa desta proteção toda não armazene senha alguma, deixe o usuário digitar a senha do que precisa de acesso.

> Ah, mas ainda assim uma aplicação em execução pode ser interceptada e pegarem a senha no momento da digitação.

Sim, e não tem nada que possa ser feito. Se o computador está comprometido, se existe a possibilidade desta interceptação, ela ocorrerá. Por isso que um computador como um todo precisa estar seguro.

Segurança é algo extremamente complicado. Em geral quando precisa mesmo, o melhor a fazer é contratar um especialista altamente capacitado. Nem sei se isto resolve bem. Mesmo que contrate um que não seja enganador. É muito fácil errar na segurança. Ou você acha que essas falhas de segurança conhecidas ocorrem só por relaxo? Claro, tem casos que é relaxo, e completo desconhecimento, mas em muitos casos, tudo que dava para fazer foi feito e ainda assim a segurança foi burlada.

Neste caso a criptografia parece estar sendo aplicada até de forma ingênua. Talvez por achar que a segurança se dará de outra forma. Dê uma lida [nessa pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/2402/101). Tenho sérias dúvidas que a criptografia foi "um sucesso", tem provas definitivas disto?

## Uma possível solução paliativa

O .NET possui uma [classe de *string* segura](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.securestring?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-5.0) que ajuda um pouco o que deseja, mas ela tem limite e só ajuda se for usada certo. A pergunta tem pouco contexto, nem sei se ajudaria este caso. A descrição é clara que apenas mantém o texto só pelo tempo necessário. Este tempo é suficiente para uma interceptação.