# Criptografia com MD5 no Java?

Tags: java, criptografia, md5

Estou criando um programa que pega um login e um password e o criptografa usando MD5,sei que MD5 não é um algoritmo que se quer pode se chamar que criptografa,mas na verdade é um hash,sendo um hash um algoritmo que mapeia dados de comprimento variável para dados de comprimento fixo,mas isto não importa,o que estou tentando fazer é o que já foi citado e a variável login com MD5 funciona normal,mas a variável password sempre retorna o mesmo resultado.

**Variáveis :**

```
String login;
String password;
MessageDigest m; 
MessageDigest m1;
```

**Processo de criptografia para MD5 :**

```
try 
{ 
m = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5"); 
m1 = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
m.update(login.getBytes(),0,login.length()); 
m1.update(password.getBytes(),0,password.length());
BigInteger login1 = new BigInteger(1, m.digest()); 
BigInteger password1 = new BigInteger(1, m.digest());


//Formatando o resultado em uma cadeia de 32 caracteres, completando com 0 caso falte 
login = String.format("%1$032X", login1); 
password = String.format("%1$032X", password1); 

System.out.println("MD5: "+ login); 
System.out.println("MD5: " + password);
}
```

**No output :**

```
login : 011DD1032ECECFB4497613E48049972C
password : D41D8CD98F00B204E9800998ECF8427E
```

No output do password sempre acaba sendo o mesmo hash,sendo que no login sempre acaba saindo um resultado diferente(um hash diferente),gostaria de saber como posso arrumar isto para sempre sair um resultado diferente assim como a variável login.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bom pessoal consegui resolver meu problema,e decidi postar aqui caso alguém queira usar o código como exemplo ou até mesmo para re-utilizar ele,o que estava faltando era resetar o MessageDigest para depois ele poder dar hash no password.

Eis o código que está arrumado :

```
try
{
    m = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
    m.update(login.getBytes(), 0, login.length());
    BigInteger login1 = new BigInteger(1, m.digest());
    login = String.format("%1$032X", login1);

    m.reset(); // <---- Reseta antes de fazer o password
    m.update(password.getBytes(), 0, password.length());
    BigInteger password1 = new BigInteger(1, m.digest());
    password = String.format("%1$032X", password1);

    System.out.println(login);
    System.out.println(password);
}
```

Comment: Que bom que você resolveu seu problema, mas de todo modo lembre-se que na prática [MD5 não é um bom método para proteger senhas](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/2402/215). A propósito, por que você está hasheando o login?