# Criptografar o banco de dados é uma medida eficiente? Como proteger dados contra vazamentos?

Tags: banco-de-dados, segurança

Com os recentes problemas de vazamentos de senhas e informações pessoais oriundos dos mais diversos sites, evidencia-se a falta de zelo quanto ao armazenamento de tais informações por parte de certas empresas, demonstrando total desprezo pela confia do usuário que fornece tais dados tidos como sensíveis.

Alguns programadores embora utilizem *hashs* para proteger as senhas, ignoram o *salt*. Ou então, embora as senhas sejam protegidas, outras informações, como *e-mails, endereços e números de cartões de crédito* são salvas em texto puro.

1. A criptografia do banco de dados é a solução?
2. Quais os prós e contras desta solução?
3. E quanto ao uso de algoritmos *hash*, quais devem ser utilizados e qual a melhor forma?
4. Como demais informações *(ex: e-mail, telefone e endereços)* devem ser armazenadas?
5. O quanto essas medidas afetam o desempenho das aplicações?

Comment: Achei muitas perguntas para uma pergunta só.

Comment: Alguma das respostas resolveu o seu problema? Acha que pode aceitar uma delas? Se ainda não o fez, veja o [tour] como fazer isso. Você ajudaria a comunidade identificando a melhor solução para você. Só pode aceitar apenas uma delas, mas pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo.

Comment: A criptografia proteje à um acesso ao dado bruto (um datafile Oracle) por exemplo, mas em algum momento o dado pode ser extraído e vazado de forma indevida jogando no ralo o trabalho de se manter um dado criptografado. Mas para dados muito $$$ensíveis talvez se faça necessário.

Answer (score 7):

Sim, é. Se usar um mecanismo adequado, geralmente fornecido pelos próprios bancos de dados.

Alguns fornecem a possibilidade de criptografar só algumas partes, uma coluna, por exemplo.

Também podem oferecer métodos de criptografia diferentes. Precisa escolher um adequado ao que deseja.

Note que senha costuma merecer uma criptografia diferente do banco de dados. Um banco de dados costuma ser criptografado de forma que os dados possam ser facilmente descriptografados quando necessários. Geralmente não queremos que senhas sejam descriptografadas, o que dá mais segurança.

Dados que precisam ser descriptografados (e-mail, telefone e endereços) oferecem menos segurança porque em algum lugar será descriptografado, em algum lugar terá um chave e um algoritmo de descriptografia. Tem algumas técnicas para aumentar a segurança, mas em um sistema comprometido não tem muito o que fazer. A única forma de dar uma segurança maior, mas longe de ser perfeita, é a descriptografia só ocorrer no cliente usando chaves pública e privada.

Os vazamentos ocorrem porque usam técnicas inadequadas de segurança.

Uma das falhas mais comuns com senhas é a falta de um bom *salt*. Outra é usar *hash* ruim.

Tudo isso está na pergunta e criar.

Qual é a alternativa de não fazer a criptografia? Deixar sem nada? Me parece óbvio que é pior.

Vai afetar um pouco o desempenho, mas nada forte.

De resto pode ser lido na pergunta: [Como fazer hash de senhas de forma segura?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/2402/101). É praticamente uma duplicata (pelo menos nessa parte).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score 1):

Existe uma lista de boas práticas para segurança, chamada OWASP, ela é muito confiável, pois é gerida por um consórcio e atualizada anualmente:
https://owasp.org/

**1 -** Você não especificou o banco de dados.
Existem bancos de dados mais novos que são fracos no quesito segurança, então avalie bem antes de adotar um em produção.
Quanto ao Postgres você pode:

- criptografar colunas
- criptografar o arquivo do banco de dados
- criptografar toda a comunicação entre o teu sistema e o banco de dados usando SSL.

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/encryption-options.html
Não existe resposta fácil e simples para isso, precisaria entender teu contexto, mas essas são algumas das opções que você poderia adotar, nesse link há mais outras.

**2 -** Prós são óbvios:

- **Para criptografia de colunas** é o caso do invasor ter acesso remoto à instância do teu banco de dados, e ele usar um terminal client para se conectar e consultar os dados, ao fazer isso, ele terá os dados criptografados nas colunas.
- **Criptografando o arquivo do banco de dados** caso do invasor conseguir acessar a máquina que hospeda o banco de dados, ele conseguirá copiar o arquivo, mas não conseguirá subir uma instância do banco de dados na máquina dele.
- **A criptografia SSL do BD com os clients** impede que alguém "escute" a rede e rapte dados trafegados.
- Se o invasor conseguir ter acesso de usuário, ele vai conseguir obter os dados de qualquer forma, porém limitado ao o que o usuário consegue consultar, leia o final dessa resposta que explico como limitar o acesso à quantidade de dados.

Já os Contras pode-se incluir aí a manutenção mais complicada e desempenho, mais uma vez, não sabemos teu volume dados, certamente você precisará fazer benchmarks, mas a prioridade deve ser segurança.

3 - Já a respeito de algoritmos hash, você pode dar uma olhada no hashing competition:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Password_Hashing_Competition
https://www.password-hashing.net/
https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/Password_Storage_Cheat_Sheet.html
A boa prática é usar o hash mais lento da atualidade, e aplicar salt.
Jamais deixe o salt em código-fonte.

4 - O ideal é ter políticas de acesso ao banco de dados de produção o mais restritivo possível, já nos bancos de dados de homologação e desenvolvimento o correto é trocar os dados sensíveis por uma carga de dados aleatórios.

5 - O quanto essas medidas afetam o desempenho das aplicações?
Essa é uma pergunta que sempre cairá na resposta mais emblemática da TI:
**DEPENDE** DE MUITOS FATORES

Você não perguntou, mas creio eu que uma das maiores preocupações deveria ser:
E se o invasor criptografar meus dados impedindo que meus negócios continuem normalmente?
Por conta disso, uma medida de segurança é ter backups regulares, um histórico de backups, talvez em dois servidores, um para os mais recentes e outro para mais antigos, pois o hacker pode também conseguir comprometer teus últimos backups, com isso levando teu negócio até a falência.
Outra medida protetiva é ter toda uma política de usuários, roles, e permissões bem definidas, com um bom controle de acesso, e limitando bem o que as aplicações conseguem fazer no banco de dados.
Dados sensíveis que não costumam ser consultados em demanda, você pode proteger a tabela removendo qualquer permissão dos usuários a ela, deixando o acesso a apenas ao dono criador da tabela.
E criando view ou stored procedure que consulta apenas usando filtro do dado necessário, impedindo um select * from, por exemplo, o que dificulta muito o ataque de um hacker.

Não existe solução definitiva para segurança, nem existem fórmulas para mitigar toda e qualquer ameaça, o que existem são soluções que minimizam os riscos.

Answer (score -2):

Bom dia, para senhas eu sempre utilizo um hash `sha1` ou algo que não tenha retorno, sempre mesclo com uma chave própria como data ou um texto ou algo que varie de cliente em cliente.

Para criptografar informações do usuário aconselho a você gerar uma key para cada usuário, pode ser um md5 de um timestamp NOW() que serve.  dai você tem uma key sua q ninguém tem acesso que de uma forma ou de outra vc utilize ela junto com a key do cliente e criptografa os dados dele passando num crypt ou um base64 usando essa key.

Feito isso quem pega o db já vai ter uma enorme dificuldade de descobrir a sua key para ver o conteúdo dos hashs gerados. 
O cara teria q invadir seu sistema e ver no hardcode a key gerada.

---- vou dar um ex usando php ----

para gerar a key de cada usuário

```
$key=md5($nomedousuario.$email.date('Ymd'));
```

o que foi feito ai em cima é gerar uma key unica para este seu usuário
prox passo você tem q ter uma key sua ou mais de uma key igual eu faço mas no caso vou exemplificar apenas com 1 para você entender o processo.

```
$minhakey="87ye7jn789heyn986db87b";
```

gerei uma key aleatória que você pode tratar ela como quiser.
no meu caso eu faço o seguinte

```
$key_completa = str_replace("7"," ",$key.$minhakey);
```

o que foi feito é retirar o numero 7 ( por frescura ) e gerar uma key unica que ninguém sabe que existe, este é o segredo da coisa vc tem q ter uma chave q vc saiba como foi gerada para criptografar toda informação para que exista uma forma de ler ela.

para criptografar o conteúdo você faz o seguinte agora , vamos supor que eu tenho o e-mail do cliente e queira proteger , vai ficar assim , obs. use essas funções que estou passando para facilitar o processo.

```
function encrypt($data, $key){
    return base64_encode(
    mcrypt_encrypt(
        MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128,
        $key,
        $data,
        MCRYPT_MODE_CBC,
        "\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"
    )
);
}
function decrypt($data, $key){
    $decode = base64_decode($data);
    return mcrypt_decrypt(
                    MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128,
                    $key,
                    $decode,
                    MCRYPT_MODE_CBC,
                    "\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"
            );


}
```

para codificar

```
$email_protegido=encrypt("meuemail@gmail.com",$key_completa);
```

para decodificar

```
$email_legivel=decrypt($email_protegido,$key_completa);
```

para aumentar a segurança vá pode esconder o código que gera a key fazendo assim.

você vai transformar a função toda num base 64

```
echo base64_encode('$key_completa = str_replace("7"," ",$key.$minhakey);');
```

vai retornar isto aqui

```
JGtleV9jb21wbGV0YSA9IHN0cl9yZXBsYWNlKCI3IiwiICIsJGtleS4kbWluaGFrZXkpOw==
```

dai basta fazer assim para executar

```
eval(base64_decode('JGtleV9jb21wbGV0YSA9IHN0cl9yZXBsYWNlKCI3IiwiICIsJGtleS4kbWluaGFrZXkpOw=='));
```

assim o cara que ter cesso ao cod vai ter dificuldades para achar o que é o q.

claro que você pode usar um zend para criptografar todo seu php aumentando a segurança

Comment: Explica melhor esse negócio de gerar uma chave com horário. E isso fica onde? Na aplicação? Se for isso, o que o horário tem a ver com isso? Se o servidor for comprometido, que diferença faz? Pra que aplicar Base64? Lendo essas coisas fiquei com medo do que seja esse `crypt`.

Comment: editado, da uma olhada agora

Comment: MD5 não é bom pra senhas. Mas o mais importante não foi respondido, onde essa chave fica? Tem umas coisas tão esquisitas nesse código que não quero nem perguntar.

Comment: cara a chave fika uma parte no banco de dados e uma parte no seu hardcode escondido. como t falei c quem roubar o db nunca vai descriptografar e c alguém roubar o cod vc tem q dificultar o max possivel não so escondendo a key completa mas como vc gera ela.

Comment: Vai sim, quando o sistema está comprometido, ele pega tudo e acessa de forma normal como se nada disso existisse. Todo esse esforço serve para nada. No máximo está dificultando a manutenção da aplicação, não há dificuldade para quem roubar a informação. Na verdade a crítica colocada na pergunta é justamente por existir coisas desse tipo onde a pessoa acha que está protegendo alguma coisa e não está.

Comment: sim mas por ex c a pessoa so acessar uma das partes do sistema ele não tem acesso a outra. por isso que existe ferramentas como o zend que codificam seu código fonte, mas nada é 100% seguro.

Comment: Codificar o fonte não ajuda em nada se o sistema está comprometido, ele terá que ser decodificado para uso e isso torna a codificação inócua para esse objetivo. O problema maior é acreditar que essas soluções ajudam em alguma coisa, elas só passam uma falsa sensação de segurança.

Comment: você tem razão se o sistema não for bem escrito as possibilidades de quebra e invasão são enormes