# Qual a diferença entre codificação, criptografia e cálculo hash?

Tags: segurança, terminologia, criptografia, hash

Vejo muita confusão no site sobre os termos. **No contexto de segurança** de dados o que seria *encoding*, *encrypting* e *hashing* e em que contextos devem ser usados cada um?

Em especial, codificar serve como medida de segurança ou é usada para outra coisa? Exemplo: usar [Base64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64).

Por favor, leia e entenda a pergunta, o assunto tem um contexto específico.

Comment: Relacionada: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/2402/101

Answer (score 52, accepted):

### Encoding:

O propósito do ***Encoding*** é garantir que os dados possam ser consumidos por tipos de sistema diferentes, ex: enviar dados em binário por email ou conseguir fazer o ***encode*** de caracteres especiais numa página web, etc... É processo de colocar uma sequência de caracteres (letras, números, pontuação, e certos simbolos) em um determinado formato.

***Encoding*** transforma o formato da informação, usando metodos publicamente acessíveis para que seja facilmente revertido (*decoded*) e *encoded* (alterar o formato) consoante as necessidades. A informação não precisa de uma chave para ser ***decoded***, a unica coisa que é preciso é o algoritmo usado para o próprio ***encode***.

O objetivo **NÃO** é tornar a informação secreta, mas sim para garantir que a informação possa ser consumida corretamente consoante o sistema/encoding que temos/queremos.

***Base64 encode***, pertence a este grupo.

**Então para que serve o *encoding* de dados?** Serve para, consoante as necessidades, optimizar o armazenamento ou a transmição destes dados, mudar o formato original para que possa ser usado por algum processo externo. Alguns dos casos onde ***encoding/decoding*** é usado:

- Compilação e execução de um programa (ex: *plain text* para binário)
- *networking communication*
- Conversão de ficheiros
- Reduzir o tamanho de ficheiros para para armazenamento ou transmição

Alguns dos tipos de encoding mais conhecidos são: UTF-8, UTF-16, ASCII, iso-8859-1, unicode, ansi. [Para quem quiser saber mais sobre estes ou outros tipos](http://www.rhyshaden.com/encoding.htm).

[Encoding não é encriptação](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4070693/what-is-the-purpose-of-base-64-encoding-and-why-it-used-in-http-basic-authentica/4070709#4070709)

**Para os outros dois pontos (visto que são componentes da mesma ciência) abaixo vou começar por dizer:**

## O que é a Criptografia?

Falando da palavra em si, da sua origem, ***crypto*** quer dizer "escondido, secreto", e ***graphy*** aponta para "escrita, representação, gravação, descrição, uma maneira de desenhar etc...".

Na sua prática, como todos sabemos, existe (não como ciência assumida claro) uns milhares de anos antes do primeiro computador, via carta por ex.

Encriptação então, é a ciência que estuda as técnicas da  comunicação/escrita secreta na potencial presença de *third parties*, que neste contexto é quem não deve ter acesso à informação de forma esplicíta/legível. Vários
aspectos acerca de [*Information Security* (segurança da informação)](https://security.stackexchange.com/), confidencialidade de dados e sua integridade, autenticação são pontos centrais da criptografia moderna.

E quem precisa disto? Todos nós. No ato mais simples de colocar uma *password* e envia-la para ser validada pelo servidor, esse processo deve acontecer através de HTTPS (em que o transporte da informação não foge ao protocolo HTTP, mas em que esta vai encriptada) por ex. Esta abilidade de proteger e assegurar a informação é vital (e irá ser cada vez mais) nos dias de hoje, em que muita informação já não é guardada nas máquinas dos respetivos donos, mas sim em local publico (*clouds*, por exemplo), já para não falar do crescimento exponêncial movimentações de dinheiros via *internet*.

Leituras complementares:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptography

http://www.brighthub.com/computing/enterprise-security/articles/65254.aspx

http://www.cyber-rights.org/crypto/cryptog.htm

### Encryption

O propósito da ***encriptação*** é tranformar a informação de maneira a que fique secreta, codifica-la por assim dizer, para que os "outros" mesmo que a tenham em seu poder não a conseguirem decifrar/consumir, torna-la perceptível. Apenas para as entidades legítimas destinatárias da informação é que esta é desencriptada e é possível consumi-la, ler de maneira perceptível a informação.

A ***encriptação*** tranforma o formato da informação em outro formato de tal forma que só as entidades especificas (donas do sistema) consigam reverter a transformação. De uma maneira geral é usado uma/duas chave(s) que são secretas, em conjunto com o texto e o algoritmo de encriptação, tanto o algoritmo como a(s) chave(s) são precisos tanto para encriptar como para desencriptar.

Uma chave de encriptação é um conjunto de caracteres que no processo de encriptação é utilizado para "bagunçar"/codificar os dados de forma a que estes fiquem encriptados, quanto mais randomica/imprevísivel esta key for mais dificil será que alguém externo ao processo consiga desencriptar a informação.

#### Existem dois tipos principais de encriptação:

**Encriptação Simétrica**

Aqui o importante é saber que tanto o ponto A (onde é encriptado) como o ponto B (onde é desencriptado) precisam de ter acesso à mesma chave de encriptação.

As operações com base na chave simétrica são mais simples do que as com assimétrica (abaixo explicada), pois existe uma única chave entre os intervinientes. A chave, na prática, representa um segredo, partilhado entre duas ou mais partes, que podem ser usadas para manter um canal confidencial de informação. Usa-se uma única chave, partilhada por ambos os interlocutores, na premissa de que esta é conhecida apenas por eles.

Tipos de algoritmos de chave simétrica:

- Os algoritmos de chave simétrica podem ser divididos em [cifras de fluxo](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cifra_de_fluxo) (ou contínuas) e em [cifras por bloco](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cifra_de_bloco).

  - As cifras de fluxo cifram os bits da mensagem um a um, enquanto as cifras por bloco pegam um número de bits e cifram como uma única unidade.
  - Os blocos cifrados aceitam um número de bits e cifram em unidades. Um bloco de 64 bits é comum. O algoritmo AES aprovado pelo NIST em dezembro de 2001 usa blocos de 128 bits.

Exemplos de algoritmos simétricos populares e bem reputados incluem:

- [AES](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Encryption_Standard)
- Twofish
- [Serpent](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serpent)
- [Blowfish](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blowfish)
- [CAST5](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAST5)
- [RC4](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/RC4)
- [3DES](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/3DES) (baseado no DES)
- IDEA

Este tipo de encriptação é usado:

- Em serviços que armazenam dados em nome de utilizadores, clouds, *backups*
- Criar um canal seguro entre um ponto A e um ponto B de um *network*, partindo-se do príncipio que existe uma maneira viável/segura e em separado de enviar a chave de encriptação.

Limitações:

A desvantagem dos algoritmos de chave simétrica é a exigência de uma única chave secreta compartilhada, com uma cópia em cada extremidade. As chaves estão sujeitas à descoberta potencial por um adversário criptográfico, por isso necessitam ser mudadas freqüentemente e mantidas seguras durante a distribuição e no serviço. Essa exigência de escolher, distribuir e armazenar chaves sem erro e sem perda, é conhecida como “gerenciamento de chave”.

A fim de garantir a comunicação segura entre toda uma população de ***n*** pessoas, um total de ***(n(n-1))/2*** chaves são necessárias. Frequentemente os algoritmos assimétricos são muito mais lentos, são usados no início de uma sessão para distribuir chaves simétricas, então os algoritmos de chave simétrica mais elevados aumentam sua velocidade. Os mesmos problemas de distribuição de chave de confiança existem ainda no nível assimétrico, mas são um tanto mais tratáveis. Entretanto, a chave simétrica é gerada quase sempre em tempo real. Os algoritmos de chave simétrica não podem ser usados para finalidades de autenticação. Para finalidades de autenticação, geralmente são usadas funções de hash, por exemplo MD5 (já obsoleto na data desta resposta).

[Leitura complementar](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algoritmo_de_chave_sim%C3%A9trica)

**Encriptação Assimétrica:** (ou Criptografia de chave pública)

Esta difere da Encriptação Simétrica na maneira de como funciona em relação à chave de encriptação/desencriptação, pois esta usa duas chaves, uma para encriptar outra para desencriptar, enquanto na Simétrica é usada a mesma chave. Aqui a chave de encriptação de uma maneira geral é publica mas a chave de desencriptação é privada/secreta que coexiste no local onde vai ser processada a desencriptação.

Este tipo de Criptografia, Assimétrica ou de chave pública, é frequentemente usada para garantir a segurança da comunicação eletrônica sobre um ambiente interconectado aberto tal como a internet, sem depender de um canal encoberto até para uma troca de chaves. Ambientes interconectados abertos são suscetíveis a uma variedade de problemas de segurança de comunicação tais quais ataque do [homem-no-meio (man in the middle](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ataque_man-in-the-middle)) e outras ameaças à segurança. Propriedades de segurança necessárias para comunicação tipicamente incluem que a comunicação que está sendo enviada não deva ser legível durante a transição (preservando confidencialidade), a comunicação não deve ser modificada durante a transição (preservando a integridade da comunicação), a comunicação deve ser originada por uma parte identificada (autenticidade do remetente) e para assegurar o não-repúdio (a não negação de envio da mensagem). Combinar criptografia de chave pública com um método de Encriptação de Chave Pública Envelopada (ECPE),[3](https://security.stackexchange.com/) permite o envio seguro de uma comunicação sobre um ambiente interconectado aberto.

Uma analogia para encriptação de chave pública é a de uma caixa de correio. A caixa de correio é exposta e acessível ao público – sua localização (o endereço da rua) é, em essência, a chave pública. Qualquer um que saiba o endereço pode chegar e colocar uma mensagem escrita na caixa de correio. Porém, apenas a pessoa que possui a chave pode abrir a caixa e ler a mensagem.

É usada em:

- [Assinaturas digitais](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assinatura_digital), nas quais a mensagem é assinada com a chave privada do emissor e pode ser verificada por qualquer um que tenha acesso à chave pública do emissor. Essa verificação prova que o emissor teve acesso à chave privada, logo, ele provavelmente é a pessoa associada à chave pública. Isto também garante que a mensagem não foi adulterada, uma vez que qualquer manipulação da mensagem irá resultar em modificações no resumo de mensagem (em inglês message digest) codificado, a qual, caso contrário, se mantém imutável entre emissor e recipiente.
- Encriptação de chave pública, na qual a mensagem é encriptada com a chave pública do destinatário. A mensagem não pode ser decriptada por ninguém que não possua a chave privada correspondente, o qual é presumidamente o proprietário da chave e a pessoa associada com a chave pública. Isto é utilizado numa tentativa de assegurar [confidencialidade](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confidencialidade).
- [SSL](https://www.digicert.com/ssl.htm) para segurança das conecções entre browser e *website*, e outros serviços de *network* ([aprofundamento](https://www.digicert.com/ssl-cryptography.htm))
- [SSH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Shell) para segurança das sessões de logins com servidores remotos
- Sinalizações para software updates para que computadores saibam que vão receber dados provinientes de fonte segura

Limitações:

Um problema central com o uso da criptografia de chave pública é a confiança/prova que uma chave pública específica é autêntica, isto é, que ela é correta e pertence a pessoa ou entidade reivindicada, e não foi adulterada ou substituída por um terceiro malicioso. A abordagem mais comum para esse problema é usar uma [infraestrutura de chave pública (ICP)](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infraestrutura_de_chaves_p%C3%BAblicas), na qual um ou mais terceiros – conhecidos como [autoridades certificadoras](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autoridade_de_certifica%C3%A7%C3%A3o) – certificam a propriedade dos pares de chaves. Privacidade Muito Boa (em inglês PGP), além de ser uma estrutura de autoridade certificada, usa um esquema geralmente chamado de a "teia da verdade" (do inglês "web of trust"), que descentraliza essa autênticação de chaves públicas por um mecanismo central, e substitui endossos individuais do elo entre usuário e chave pública. Até agora, nenhuma solução completamente satisfatória para o "problema de autênticação de chave pública" foi encontrado.

Apesar da distribuição da chave pública ser mais prática do que a da chave secreta os algoritmos de cifra assimétrica são computacionalmente mais complexos que cifra simétrica, 100 a 1000 vezes mais lentos.

[Referência (en)](https://spin.atomicobject.com/2014/11/20/encryption-symmetric-asymmetric-hashing/)
[Leitura complementar](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Criptografia_de_chave_p%C3%BAblica)
[Informação complementar (en)](http://www.howtogeek.com/234642/what-is-encryption-and-why-are-people-afraid-of-it/)

**Encriptação Híbrida** (aqui coloco um terceiro tipo que não é tão usado como os dois anteriores, é uma mistura de ambos, a resposta do Inkeliz já faz *referência* e explica como funciona).

[Pdf como boa introdução aos três tipos ditos acima](https://fenix.tecnico.ulisboa.pt/downloadFile/3779574552579/7B%20Seguranca%20II%20-%20Cifra.pdf)

### Hashing

Hashing é muitas vezes dito como se fosse uma forma de encriptação, [mas não é](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4948322/fundamental-difference-between-hashing-and-encryption-algorithms) e [não é](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/2887/difference-between-encrypting-something-and-hashing-something).

Hashing serve para garantir a integridade, em que os algoritmos de ***hash*** são `one-way`, ou seja, é irreverssível/unidirecional, ex: formato em as *passwords* são armazenadas, são ***hashes***, em que a verificação é feita não com base na *password* original do utilizador, mas sim confirmando que a *password* que o utilizador colocou gera a mesma ***hash*** que está armazenada ou não.

Aqui o propósito da hash é óbvio, mesmo que alguém tenha acesso, legítimo ou não, às passwords dos utilizadores que estão armazenadas, esta pessoa nunca vai saber de facto as passwords porque tudo o que tem nas mãos são ***hashes*** irreverssíveis, em que todas as ferramentas para tentar decifra-las (convencionalmente chamadas de *password crackers*) apenas usam uma grande lista de possíveis *passwords* e vão comparando, fazendo ***hash*** de uma a uma e comparando com as ***hashes*** que têm para decifrar.

Ou seja, ***hashing*** é ótimo para uso em qualquer ocasião em que queremos comparar um valor com outro que tenhamos armazenado mas, sem armazenar o verdadeiro valor por razões de segurança.

Uma hash tem três importantes propriedades:

- O mesmo conjunto de caracteres vai sempre produzir a mesma hash
- É irreversível (não pode ser 'desencriptado') (como explicado antes)
- É/deve ser impossível a mesma hash para duas strings diferentes, a isto chama-se colisão no contexto de *cryptografia*

[Outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/2402/como-fazer-hash-de-senhas-de-forma-segura) muito completa no SOPT acerca disto.

Alguns dos mais conhecidos metodos de Hash são: MD5 (obsoleto), SHA-1, SHA-256. [Para quem quiser saber mais alguns metodos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_hash_functions)

**Fontes:**

http://www.securityinnovationeurope.com/blog/whats-the-difference-between-hashing-and-encrypting

https://danielmiessler.com/study/encoding-encryption-hashing-obfuscation/#gs.Ns30xvU

https://spin.atomicobject.com/2014/11/20/encryption-symmetric-asymmetric-hashing/

E um bocadinho eu.

Comment: depois dá pra acrescentar uns detalhezinhos aí, mas no geral já responde bem. +1

Comment: De fato acho que todas respostas podem ficar um pouco melhor, mas essa está correta e vai no ponto. Pra aceitação eu esperaria mais detalhes, principalmente na parte de criptografia mesmo.

Comment: O SSL usa encriptação simétrica, o SSH também. Porém, eles fazem uma troca de chaves (usando ECDH, ou ECDHE especificamente no caso do TLS).

Answer (score 12):

**Encodings** são 'linguagens' usadas para representar informação através de padrões bem definidos e conhecidos de bits.

Assim como você sabe que a sequência de letras 'm-a-ç-ã' representa uma fruta em português, um programa sabe que a sequência `0x6D 0x61 0xE7 0xE3` representa esta mesma palavra em UTF-8.

Usar enconding para segurança seria como escrever uma mensagem em russo e torcer para que ninguém, além da pessoa para quem você mandou a mensagem, saiba falar essa língua.

**Encriptação** é um meio de garantir que somente pessoas autorizadas leiam uma mensagem.

No contexto da computação geralmente usa-se uma 'chave' para trancar uma mensagem. Dependendo do algoritmo, a mesma chave (algoritmo simétrico) ou uma chave diferente (algoritmo assimétrico) é usada para recuperar o conteúdo original.

**Hashing** é uma técnica usada para associar um conteúdo qualquer a um valor. A relevância desta família de algorítmos para a segurança é o conjunto de características que os (bons) algorítmos apresentam:

- Calcular o hash de um conteúdo é rápido. Achar o conteúdo que produziu um hash é computacionalmente difícil/impossível.
- Mudar qualquer parte do conteúdo altera completamente o hash produzido para o conteúdo.

Essas características são muito úteis para armazenar informações sigilosas e garantir a integridade de um conteúdo, respectivamente.

Answer (score 7):

## Codificação:

O encoding é simplesmente dar um novo "significado" para algum byte. O UTF-8, por exemplo, é uma codificação que converte um byte (ou uma sequencia de bytes) em caracteres unicode. O Base64 é uma outra codificação, converte uma sequencia arbitraria de bytes para alguns outros bytes específicos, normalmente ele é bastante utilizado para que possa transferir dados binários como se fossem textos.

Ele não tem qualquer relação com criptografia, o objetivo deles não é tornar o dado ilegível ou irrecuperável.

## Encriptação:

A encriptação é tornar uma informação ilegível para todos que não possuem a chave correta, apenas. A encriptação faz com que um dado arbitrário, em combinação com uma chave (um valor uniformemente aleatório, mantido em segredo e com grande o suficiente) e um nonce (uma valor único por uso), resulte num novo conjunto de bytes que é ilegível para todos, exceto aqueles que possuem a chave.

Todos os algorítimos práticos (AES, Serpent, ChaCha20, Salsa20...) são vulneráveis a buscas exaustivas, mas isso é insignificante, já que não há poder computacional para isso.

Note, que a encriptação não garante integridade, apenas garante a confidencialidade. Alguns algoritmos adicionalmente incluem um MAC, para impedir a modificação do texto encriptado.

Existem três tipos de encriptação:

- **Simétrica:**
  Todos os usuários envolvidos precisam compartilhar a mesma chave, tanto para encriptar quanto para decifrar, exemplo de uso é o SSL, que utiliza encriptação simétrica (AES, ChaCha20...) baseada numa chave temporária usando DH.
- **Assimétrica:**
  Cada usuário possui duas chaves, de usos diferentes, a chave privada é responsável por criar uma chave pública e também capaz de decifrar o texto. Enquanto isso, uma chave pública é capaz apenas de encriptar um dado arbitrário. Isso permite compartilharmos a chave pública para qualquer pessoa e somente o detentor da chave privada poderá decifrar. Ele é usado em OpenPGP, por exemplo, onde utiliza RSA.
- **Hibrida:**
  Um usuário cria uma mesma chave privada simétrica e encripta o texto usando ela. Depois, ele encripta esta chave privada usando a chave pública de cada pessoa, que está autorizada a decifrar. Isso é bastante usado para poupar poder computacional, já que encriptações simétricas são mais rápidas e também permite encriptar um mesmo texto para várias pessoas de maneira ainda mais curta. Isso também é usado pelo OpenPGP.

*A criptografia simétrica e assimétrica não é apenas usada para encriptação, a criptografia de chave pública (assimétrica) é usado também para assinaturas digitais e para acordo de chaves, por exemplo. Mas, isso é fora do tópico aqui.*

Caso haja preocupações contra "computadores quanticos", os algoritmos simétricos (AES-256, Serpent-256, ChaCha20, Salsa20...) são seguros, os algoritmos de chave pública não possuem o mesmo luxo, tanto o curvas elípticas quanto RSA estão em risco.

## Hashing:

Especificamente no contexto de criptografia, a hash é uma função que possui como objetivo ser resistente a colisão, resistentes a pre-imagem e ataques de pre-segunda imagem. Embora isso não seja uma regra, boas funções de hashes também são indistinguíveis de um resultado aleatório, e claro eles são imprevisíveis por consequência.

A hash é uma das funções mais versáteis e simples da criptografia. Em linhas gerais, ele possui uma única entrada, um dado arbitrário, e terá uma saída de tamanho fixo. Novamente, buscas exaustivas sempre vão funcionar para criar colisões, mas nós assumimos que isto é insignificante, já que não há poder computacional para isso.

Seus usos são os mais diversos possíveis, eles são usados para verificar modificações de arquivos (como no Git), são usado em sistemas de detecção de intrusão (HIDS), são usados como prova de trabalho (como no Bitcoin)... Mas, ele também pode ser parte de algo muito maior, dai vem a maior confusão de todas.

Um algoritmo de hash pode ser utilizado para outras finalidades, se não verificar modificações de arquivos e etc:

- **Criar nova chave baseada em uma chave (KBKDF):**
  Você pode criar uma nova N chaves mesmo usando uma única chave., usando HMAC ou HKDF, por exemplo. O Bitcoin usa isso para criar chaves para "carteiras determinísticas", o TLS usa HMAC como um PRF para criar chaves.
- **Criar nova chave baseada em uma senha (PBKDF):**
  Tendo um dado de baixa entropia é possível torna-la forte e indistinguível de um resultado aleatório usando maior poder computacional e hashes. O PBKDF2 usa uma iteração de HMAC para atrasar ataques de buscas exaustivas, o Scrypt funciona de maneira similar e também o Argon2 é também baseado numa outra função de hash, o Blake2. Qualquer site descente usa derivações de senhas para armazenar a senha do usuário de maneira segura.
- **Criar garantias de integridade:**
  Você pode garantir que uma informação já foi verificada por você e que a informação está integra usando HMAC, ele uma chave é combinada com um texto. Isto é bastante usado para complementar encriptações, já que você pode mandar mensagens encriptadas e imutáveis, mas também é preciso que ambos possuem a mesma chave.
- **Criar provas de trabalho:**
  Você pode usar apenas o esforço computacional usando os algoritmos de hashes. Você pode, por exemplo, enviar um valor X e pedir para que o usuário retorne um valor N, onde `H(X || N)` é maior que Y. A verificação é rápida, enquanto encontrar o valor pode não ser.
  ...

*Note, existem hashes não-criptográficas, onde não garante resistência contra colisões e etc. Um exemplo, é o SipHash, que foi desenvolvido para mitigar um DoS em Hash-Tables, chamado de Hash DoS.*

As funções de hashes participam de diversos outros casos de usos, mas seu uso errado pode criar graves erros. Esteja sempre atendo aos requisitos de cada algoritmo e quais os objetivos eles cumprem.

As funções de hashes mais recentes (como Blake2, SHA-3...) possuem recursos adicionais, incluindo recursos equivalentes ao HMAC, onde há duas entradas. Além disso, esses algorítimos permitem usar tamanhos diferentes, não padrões, assim poderá ter um resultado de uma hash de 8 bytes ou um resultado de 256GB, usando o Blake2XOF.