# Base64 e MD5 - Java

Tags: java, criptografia

Quais são as diferenças entre MD5 e Base64 para criptografia? Qual é o mais seguro?

Li que o MD5 é o mais utilizado, mas queria entender o motivo.

Comment: Md5 é apenas hash, base 64 é um tipo de codificação

Comment: Pode me dar um exemplo de situações de uso de MD5 e Base64?

Comment: Base 64 não é um mecanismo de criptografia, é um esquema de codificação. É facilmente revertida, por isso não é uma boa opção para proteger dados críticos.

A abordagem comum para senhas é hash-los com algo como MD5 e, em seguida, armazenar o hash. Quando o usuário fizer logon novamente, digite a senha de entrada e compare-a ao hash armazenado.
A codificação Base 64 é geralmente utilizada para transmitir dados binários através de um mecanismo que apenas permite o texto ASCII. Resposta traduzida [daqui](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3993958/5325043)

Comment: Entendi, Denis.

Muito obrigado cara!

Comment: @DenisRudneideSouza Por favor, considere transformar seu comentário em uma resposta. Mesmo que considere algo pequeno e simples, é melhor para para os futuros visitantes e então o Guilherme pode escolher sua resposta como certa. Abraços!

Comment: Relacionado: ["Qual a diferença entre codificação, criptografia e cálculo hash?"](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/162369/215) Sobre o MD5 ser mais utilizado, no passado ele era considerado seguro, mas já não é mais há muito tempo, no entanto muitos desenvolvedores em todo o mundo ainda não se deram conta disso - por isso ele continua sendo popular, apesar da insegurança. Para mais detalhes, ver ["Como fazer hash de senhas de forma segura?"](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/2402/215)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Base 64 não é um mecanismo de criptografia, é um esquema de codificação. É facilmente revertida, por isso não é uma boa opção para proteger dados críticos.

A codificação Base 64 é geralmente utilizada para transmitir dados binários através de um mecanismo que apenas permite o texto ASCII.

Antigamente a abordagem comum para senhas era hash-los com algo como MD5 e, em seguida, armazenar o hash no banco de dados. Quando o usuário faz logon novamente, a senha é digitada, o hash é recalculado e verificado com o já existente no banco de dados.

Você pode verificar [nessa](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/2402/como-fazer-hash-de-senhas-de-forma-segura) pergunta, qual e melhor forma de realizar hash de senhas de forma segura atualmente, já que o MD5 não é mais adequado para esse propósito.

Fonte: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3993958/5325043

Comment: Boa resposta, exceto pela parte do MD5. **Nunca** use MD5 pra proteção de senhas, a resposta que serviu de base para esta resposta está bastante desatualizada (foi originalmente respondida em 2010), e em sua versão atual já salienta que o MD5 é inadequado para esse propósito (embora sua sugestão de usar SHA-1 também não é aceitável atualmente). Para mais detalhes, ver a pergunta ["Como fazer hash de senhas de forma segura?"](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/2402/215)