# O que é uma cifra?

Tags: terminologia, criptografia

Várias vezes eu encontro algumas [perguntas relacionadas a cifras](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=cifra) aqui no SO<sup>pt</sup>. Entretanto não encontrei nenhuma definição da mesma. Então,

- O que seria uma cifra e qual a sua função?
- Vi que existem vários tipos. Elas estão relacionadas a criptografia como um hash ou como codificação, geralmente?
- Essas podem ser usadas em qualquer linguagem?

Comment: "Cifra" é basicamente o nome que se dá aos algoritmos de encriptação ou decriptação.

Comment: Acho que base64 nem chega a ser considerado criptografia, é um tipo de codificação. Tenho certeza sobre a terminologia nesse caso.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Acredito que "Cifra" seja um termo bem genérico, mas se refere ao algoritmo usado pela encriptação e decriptação do texto, ou seja como o texto-plano se tornará um texto-cifrado e como ele será decifrado.

---

Uma cifra pode ser classificada por dois tipo:

- Estilo de cifra:

  - Cifra de Bloco (Block Cipher) (EX. CBC)
  - Cifra de Fluxo (Stream Cipher) (EX. CTR, ChaCha)

*Historicamente podem citar outros tipos de cifra, como a cifra de substituição e etc...*

- Estilo de chave:

  - Cifra simétrica (criptografia de chave privada) (EX: DES, AES)
  - Cifra assimétrica (criptografia de chave pública) (EX: RSA)

Talvez existam mais tipos de classificação, afinal algumas cifras como o GCM e CCM podem também garantir confidencialidade, integridade e autenticidade. Enquanto outras como CBC apenas a confidencialidade, exigindo que use externamente algum outro tipo de autenticação, *como EtM via HMAC*.

---

> O que seria uma cifra e qual a sua função?

A cifra é o algoritmo que será utilizado para gerar o texto-cifrado e para que consiga descifrar o texto-cifrado, para que possamos ler. A cifra de CBC e CTR são diferentes, ambos são usados para AES e ambos geram textos cifrados e descifram o texto.

A cifra é como o texto será criptografado.

> Vi que existem vários tipos. Elas estão relacionadas a criptografia como um hash ou como codificação, geralmente?

Nenhum dos dois. A cifra está relacionada a encriptação, a geração de textos-cifrados.

Codificação não envolve chave, a Base64 é apenas uma "representação alternativa", da mesma forma que pode usar Hexadecimal ou Decimal.

*Você pode codificar um texto-cifrado, por exemplo no OpenPGP existe o "ascii-armored" que converte uma assinatura binária para ASCII, permitindo melhor visualização e distribuição, por exemplo.*

Já a hash não tem muito haver aqui, ela não é reversível e portanto não usa nenhuma cifra. Ela também é conhecida como "resumo criptográfico", pode achar assim alguns livros. Ele é feito para que N bytes de entrada resulte sempre em uma saída de tamanho fixo, em resumo é usado para garantir a integridade. Apenas para complementar o caso, também existem a *Keyed-Hash*, que são hashes que possuem chaves, como o HMAC.

[Qual a diferença entre codificação, criptografia e cálculo hash?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/162369/qual-a-diferen%C3%A7a-entre-codifica%C3%A7%C3%A3o-criptografia-e-c%C3%A1lculo-hash)

> Essas podem ser usadas em qualquer linguagem?

Usada podem ser utilizada, mas muito provavelmente você vai acabar usando uma biblioteca escrita em C. Por exemplo o OpenSSL e o Libsodium (e muitos outros) são escritos em C, C é quase uma regra para criptografia.

Entretanto várias linguagens implementam bibliotecas criptografias, no PHP por exemplo, é possível usar criptografia assimétrica usando o OpenSSL via `openssl_public_encrypt()` ou usando Libsodium via `crypto_box()`. Agora, nenhuma das duas bibliotecas estão escritas em PHP, você está usando algo escrito em C.