# Como verificar se uma String esta codificada em base64?

Tags: javascript, email, vue.js, base64, encode

Estou trabalhando numa aplicação de emails utilizando VueJs/Quasar no cliente e HapiJS no servidor, e alguns emails(depende o remetente) vem com o texto codificado em base64, e outros não.

Aí que vem o problema, para resolver isso preciso achar um meio de identificar se o corpo de email está em base64 e somente depois de identificar mandar ele decodificado para o cliente, e se ele não estiver criptografado somente enviar para o cliente

Comment: Base64 não deveria ser usado para criptografia, já que ele não esconde a informação

Comment: Entendi, ainda não conheço muito esse negócio de base64, só sei que alguns emails vem em base64 e outros não...

Comment: Creio que essa seja uma boa leitura: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/162369/64969

Comment: Então no meu caso, eu não estou criptografando, apenas estou codificando para que a informação possa ser lida por qualquer sistema, certo??

Comment: isso mesmo. O base64 surgiu no contexto de email para fazer principalmente a transferência de arquivos anexos binários. No caso, foi uma limitação do protocolo que só permitia caracteres ASCII imprimíveis, espaçamentos é quebras de linha

Comment: Ok então, muito obrigado pelo esclarecimento e pela ajuda @Jefferson Quesado

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Podes usar expressão regular para verificar se uma string está codificada em base64 ou não:

```
^([A-Za-z0-9+/]{4})*([A-Za-z0-9+/]{4}|[A-Za-z0-9+/]{3}=|[A-Za-z0-9+/]{2}==)$
```

Exemplo:

```
var base64 = /^([A-Za-z0-9+/]{4})*([A-Za-z0-9+/]{4}|[A-Za-z0-9+/]{3}=|[A-Za-z0-9+/]{2}==)$/;

base64.test("Ola1234345345");             // retorna false
base64.test("ZXdyd2Vyd2Vyd2VycXJxd2VycXdlcnF3ZXJxd2VyZXdxcg==");   // retorna true
```

ou podes usar uma simples função:

```
function isBase64(str) {
    try {
        return btoa(atob(str)) == str;
    } catch (err) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Muito obrigado pela ajuda @13dev... Me poupou de horas de pesquisa