# Asp.net Identity Descriptografar

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-identity

É possível descriptografar a senha gerada pelo Asp.Net Identity?

Comment: Por que a pergunta é muito ampla?

Comment: @LINQ _herd behavior_?

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado Bem provável

Answer (score 6):

Não.

As senhas do Identity passam por um processo de [*hash*](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fun%C3%A7%C3%A3o_hash), que é uma forma de "embaralhar" a informação em apenas uma via, ou seja, uma vez que a informação passou por este processo, não há como obter a informação original.

Essa é a principal ideia de se usar um algoritmo de *hash*.

Veja algumas publicações sobre o assunto:

- [Qual a diferença entre codificação, criptografia e cálculo hash?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/162369/18246)
- [Como fazer hash de senhas de forma segura?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/2402/18246)

A título de curiosidade, aqui estão as implementações padrões usadas pelo Identity:

Método de *hashing*

```
public static string HashPassword(string password)
{
    byte[] salt;
    byte[] buffer2;
    if (password == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("password");
    }
    using (Rfc2898DeriveBytes bytes = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(password, 0x10, 0x3e8))
    {
        salt = bytes.Salt;
        buffer2 = bytes.GetBytes(0x20);
    }
    byte[] dst = new byte[0x31];
    Buffer.BlockCopy(salt, 0, dst, 1, 0x10);
    Buffer.BlockCopy(buffer2, 0, dst, 0x11, 0x20);
    return Convert.ToBase64String(dst);
}
```

Método de verificação:

```
public static bool VerifyHashedPassword(string hashedPassword, string password)
{
    byte[] buffer4;
    if (hashedPassword == null)
    {
        return false;
    }
    if (password == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("password");
    }
    byte[] src = Convert.FromBase64String(hashedPassword);
    if ((src.Length != 0x31) || (src[0] != 0))
    {
        return false;
    }
    byte[] dst = new byte[0x10];
    Buffer.BlockCopy(src, 1, dst, 0, 0x10);
    byte[] buffer3 = new byte[0x20];
    Buffer.BlockCopy(src, 0x11, buffer3, 0, 0x20);
    using (Rfc2898DeriveBytes bytes = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(password, dst, 0x3e8))
    {
        buffer4 = bytes.GetBytes(0x20);
    }
    return ByteArraysEqual(buffer3, buffer4);
}
```

Os dois vieram [desta pergunta do SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20622428/4190610) que, por sua vez, usou o código do próprio [ASP.NET Identity que está no Codeplex](https://aspnetidentity.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core/Crypto.cs).