# Visualizar senha com hash no banco de dados, decodificada

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Estou salvando as senhas no banco com hash, e agora quero visualizá-la na view, porque quando pego os dados no banco ela ainda sim fica com hash quando vou exibir ela.

`Senha:  $2y$10$G9poHdud5XJxgiQq1p0syOMEgE.wNxBwZWoA8ux.KxsnXPf4tDKni` (no banco)

`Senha: 123` (essa é a senha que cadastrei no banco)

Como a senha é salva no banco:

```
 public function CadastroSalvar (Request $request) {

 $data =  $request->all();

 $data['password'] = bcrypt($data['senha']); //primeiro campo é do banco e o outro é o campo da Request

 $data = \App\Usuario::create($data);

    return redirect()->route('UsuarioCadastro');
}
```

Comment: Isso é mesmo assim, não deves armazenar a senha em 'plain text' (tal como ela é). https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/162369/qual-a-diferen%C3%A7a-entre-codifica%C3%A7%C3%A3o-criptografia-e-c%C3%A1lculo-hash/162376#162376, https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/2402/como-fazer-hash-de-senhas-de-forma-segura/2404#2404 . Basicamente, nem os próprios administradores do sistema devem ter acesso a elas. O hash é unidirecional, não dá para reverter, apenas para comparar com outras hashs geradas

Comment: o objetivo do *hash* é não ser descriptografado :)

Comment: kkkk' serio man

Comment: vlw man vou dar uma olhada no que eu posso fazer aqui

Comment: pra que vc quer ver a senha na view? what?

Comment: kk' alterar a senha, mas vou fazer de maneira diferente kkk'

Comment: tem algorítimos q vc consegue descriptografar depois, mas no caso de senhas o mais recomendando é o hash mesmo. Não recupera, só compara pra ver se está certa e se precisar "recuperar", vc gera uma nova :)

Comment: sim sim, vlw man, é o que pretendo fazer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cara, não é possível desfazer um has, uma vez que ele tenha sido gerado.
Essa é a forma que os algoritmos digesto funcionam, ele codifica a mensagem sem utilizar uma chave para decodificação, então você não poderá ver a senha que foi digitada em texto plano, apenas comparar Hashes baseando-se em tentativa e erro.