# Qual a melhor forma de fazer uma "password" para steam Login?

Tags: php

Bom, eu tentei fazer com o steamid, como se fosse um password e receber os dados por POST, contudo acho isso uma forma muito insegura visto, que Hackers, podem alterar o steamid, e fazerem login na conta de outros usuários.

Gostaria de saber qual a melhor forma para criar um género de uma "password", ou uma hash, para que se evite ataques hackers.

Obrigado.

Comment: O que é steam exatamente?

Comment: Leia também: [Como fazer hash de senhas de forma segura](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/2402/70)

Comment: Você está utilizando o `OpenID` da Steam para fazer a autenticação?

Comment: Lembre-se sempre que se não for aquilo que procura, pode [edit] a questão e deixar mais claro o seu caso específico. Caso seja realmente outro problema, a pergunta pode ser reaberta.

Comment: Bacco, a minha pergunta não é um caso normal mas sim relativamente á Steam, porque na steam, não tem como "gerar senha".

Comment: Inkeliz estou sim usando openid.

Comment: Pode explicar melhor o sistema de OpenID? E no por que implica na falta de segurança?

Answer (score -4):

Melhor forma para criptografar em seu sistema é fazer uma senha com base na escolha do usuário com 3 criptografias.

Ex: Usuário escolhe a senha (12345)

```
Criptografia 1: MD5(12345) = Resultado: 827ccb0eea8a706c4c34a16891f84e7b
Criptografia 2: SHA-256(Cript 1) = Resultado: 30fdf15fd513fd69085f9344ff2d5d716254aa367bcac88e78ee60ad0298d606
Criptografia 3: SHA-256(Cript 2) = Resultado: 4ac3e4f57090ed6de97f2a839fe505cb05ace7d2cbc8f75865ca95cabeb173e0
```

Desta forma você consegue uma criptografia inquebrável até  momento e impossível um hacker acertar a senha.

Existem tambem as proteções do servidor para evitar sql_inject como

```
strip_tags($senha);
```

Com essas e outras utilizações anti sql_inject voce tera uma criptografia perfeita, outra coisa é voce adicionar um CheckSun ao usuario (como a Steam_id) que pega esse checksum + a senha e criptografa mais uma vez.

Com isso voce tera quase 100% de proteção a ataques, vale lembrar que para um hacker alterar a senha ou ter acesso não depende so da criptografia, tambem da proteção contra SQL_INJECT!

Comment: Dizer que `md5` ou `sha-256` gera uma criptografia inquebrável, nos dias de hoje é algo considerado um crime rs.
Se a senha possuir um `salt`, ai a historia muda

Comment: Outra coisa, utilizar múltiplos protocolos de criptografia sobre uma mesma senha, nem sempre pode ser uma boa coisa.... http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/18087/is-multiple-encryption-a-good-idea

Comment: E por fim, ate onde vi, não foi perguntado nada sobre `SQL injection`, por outro lado a intenção foi boa

Comment: Amigo, ele solicitou um meio de criar uma senha o qual HACKERS não invadissem e altera-se, apenas completei que esta solução dele não seria resolvida sem um SQLINJECT!
>> ou uma hash, para que se evite ataques hackers << // Desta forma apenas informei que somente criptografia não ira adiantar. Leia tudo por favor. E outra, md5 e sha-256 sim é totalmente seguro e inquebrável se bem usado! Obvil que uma criptografia apanas 1x ou sem um salt ou um checksum pode haver um banco de dados que ja salvou aquela senha como existe hoje, porem basta saber utilizá-lo. Deixo esse site para leitura:

Comment: deixo este site para leitura sobre criptografia do basico ao avançado para ser totalmente ou quase totalmente seguro: http://blog.thiagobelem.net/encriptando-senhas-de-forma-segura

Comment: [link1](http://security.stackexchange.com/a/19908/66435) [link2](http://meta.security.stackexchange.com/a/1132/66435) [link3](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/33531/why-improvising-your-own-hash-function-out-of-existing-hash-functions-is-so-bad) Todas da própria rede

Comment: Exatamente @MarceloBonifazio foi o que eu disse, se utilizado errado existe diversos banco de dados para fazer Choque e executar todas as combinações possíveis. Por isso utiliza-se salt ou checksum + 2 ou 3 criptografias diferentes. E claro, limita a tentativa de acesso em 2 ou 3 tentativas e bloqueia pelo IP ao acesso por x tempo, neste caso ele teria que reiniciar moldem ou reiniciar a rede toda vez o que o hacker teria que ter muito tempo e vontade para acessar. Outra que citei exemplos, é possível criar a própria criptografia e proteger ao máximo o arquivo.

Comment: Isso só gera um hash sobre hash. Seguindo essa "lógica", gerar 10 hash do original seria mais seguro, o que não faz sentido. Recomendo `password_hash`.

Comment: Na verdade para proteger contra ataques de força bruta ele se torna mais seguro, ainda mais se utilizar hash diferente junto com um salt! inclusive password_hash tambem pode ser quebrado por força bruta!

Comment: Você postou o link do blog como justificativa e o próprio autor justificou que a postagem tem problemas http://blog.thiagobelem.net/encriptando-senhas-de-forma-segura#comment-2315298464, fora que `strip_tags` para evitar SQLinjection não faz sentido algum.

Comment: A intenção de ajudar é boa, mas infelizmente o efeito é o oposto. Aprendeu errado e está repassando conhecimento errado em matéria crítica. Fica a sugestão de aproveitar a oportunidade e revisar a matéria: [Como fazer hash de senhas de forma segura](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/2402/70)