# Duvida sobre criptografia

Tags: java, android, criptografia

estou olhando como funciona a criptografia, porém, estou com uma duvida quase todos os códigos exemplos de criptografia tem um String PlainText, segue o link de um dos post que olhei: http://site.iai.art.br/radar/android-development-criptografia-baseada-em-senha/

neste poste tem o seguinte codigo:

```
public static String encrypt(String plainText, String password) throws
```

password seria a senha que eu quero criptografar certo?

mas e o plainText?

alguém poderia me explicar o que seria atribuido neste plainText?

Comment: Relacionada: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/2402

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`plaintext` é o texto que você deseja criptografar.

Enquanto `password` é a chave de proteção.

Para descriptografar você precisará utilizar a função `decrypt` passando como argumento a mesma `password` utilizada na função `encrypt`.