# O que é salt quando se trata de criptografia de senhas?

Tags: terminologia, criptografia

Pesquisando sobre criptografia, em alguns determinados casos é usado *salt*, como, provavelmente, algumas pessoas sabem. Na tradução para o inglês sei que é sal, porém dentro do âmbito desenvolvimento de software não entendi muito bem.

O que é *salt* quando se trata de criptografia de senhas? Como pode ser usado, caso seja viável?

Comment: Não seria duplicata [dessa aqui?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/2402/como-fazer-hash-de-senhas-de-forma-segura)

Comment: @diegofm não é duplicada, mas aparentemente tem algo relacionado na [resposta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/2405/35406). Vou dar uma lida lá, porque como você mesmo disse, o artigo ta muito grande. Então, talvez essa pergunta seja mais especifica sobre salt.

Comment: veja http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/2402/como-fazer-hash-de-senhas-de-forma-segura    e    https://code.tutsplus.com/pt/tutorials/understanding-hash-functions-and-keeping-passwords-safe--net-17577

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Como fazer hash de senhas de forma segura?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/2402/como-fazer-hash-de-senhas-de-forma-segura)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

O sal é utilizado para evitar que duas senhas idênticas produzam *hashes* idênticos - o que facilitaria muito o trabalho dos atacantes.

O uso da criptografia na proteção de senhas se dá por meio de uma função de *hash* - ou "embaralhamento" (mais detalhes na pergunta ["Como fazer hash de senhas de forma segura?"](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/2402/215)). Uma [função de mão única](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fun%C3%A7%C3%A3o_de_m%C3%A3o_%C3%BAnica) transforma a senha em um valor distinto, de modo que se um atacante obtiver uma cópia desse valor ele não consegue, a princípio, descobrir a senha original com facilidade. Isso é útil porque na maioria dos casos o atacante só tem uma *copia* do BD, obtida por meio de uma Injeção de SQL ou de algum backup mal gerenciado ou algo assim. Para ganhar acesso de fato ao sistema ele ainda precisa logar normalmente, e pra isso a senha original é necessária (o hash sozinho não serve, o sistema não aceita o hash como credencial).

Obter a senha a partir do hash é difícil, mas não impossível: vários sistemas são hackeados ao redor do mundo, e a maioria dos usuários não só escolhe senhas fracas como *reusam* a senha em vários serviços distintos. Se toda vez que uma senha fosse hasheada ela produzisse o mesmo valor, então uma descoberta de uma relação senha/hash feita em um sistema poderia ser usada para atacar *qualquer usuário* que usasse aquela senha em *qualquer sistema!* Existem até sites [como este](https://hashkiller.co.uk/md5-decrypter.aspx) que possuem bilhões de hashes já "quebrados", permitindo que se consulte uma senha (ou outro dado) a partir do seu hash MD5 (e o MD5 já foi muito popular como hash de senhas, ainda hoje há quem o use por falta de conhecimento de hashes melhores).

Como forçar os usuários a adotarem senhas mais e mais complexas não é uma tarefa fácil, uma alternativa é fazer com que uma mesma senha cadastrada em sistemas diferentes e/ou por usuários diferentes gere não o mesmo hash, mas hashes diferentes. Isso impede que hashes pré-computados sejam usados nos novos ataques, exigindo que o trabalho para quebrá-los seja feito todo de novo cada vez que se quiser descobrir a senha de um único usuário. A técnica do sal consiste em simplesmente prefixar a senha com um dado aleatório antes que a mesma seja hasheada. Esse sal é criado durante o registro da senha, e então armazenado junto à mesma no BD (não é necessário que o sal seja secreto, somente que ele seja **único** [com alta probabilidade]).

Sobre a forma correta de usá-los, isso depende muito do caso, e existem situações em que o uso incorreto dos mesmos pode causar problemas. No entanto, todos os algoritmos modernos concebidos especificamente visando a proteção de senhas já incorporam em si o uso do sal, de modo que basta passar o sal como parâmetro quando requisitado (se requisitado - alguns algoritmos já geram o sal pra você) e deixar que o próprio algoritmo cuide dos detalhes. Pra mais informações, ver [a pergunta relacionada citada anteriormente](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/2402/215).

No mais, evite expor publicamente o sal de qualquer usuário, mas não se preocupe demais com isso caso essa exposição seja inevitável (ex.: quando sal precisa ser enviado ao cliente, como no protocolo [SRP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Remote_Password_protocol)). Prefira um sal aleatório e razoavelmente longo em vez de um facilmente previsível (ex.: o ID do usuário no banco ou mesmo seu *username*). E toda vez que um usuário mudar sua senha, mude também o sal - importante sobretudo caso o usuário troque sua senha para outra que ele já usou anteriormente.

Answer (score 3):

O salt é a adição de caracteres, palavras, termos ou mesmo números que dão uma certa aleatoriedade aos algoritmos e ajudam a torná-los indecifráveis.

> Para exemplificar vou considerar, aqui, a inversão do texto (ABC -> CBA) como um tipo de criptografia, só para demonstrar o que acontece com SALT de forma a facilitar a compreensão humana. No mundo real, não são humanos que fazem esse trabalho, são algoritmos baseados em modelos matemáticos.

Com base no exemplo acima, imagine uma senha "123456", usando esse algoritmo (péssimo por sinal) você teria como resultado "654321".

Com uma senha conhecida e seu resultado criptografado, é possível identificar qual algoritmo foi usado para gerá-la. A complexidade do algoritmo e da senha são determinantes no tempo necessário para quebrá-la. Até hoje, matematicamente qualquer senha pode se quebrada, no entanto é importante ressaltar que em muitos casos se levariam centenas ou milhares de anos, portanto, assume-se como seguros(as) essas senhas e algoritmos.

Embora no mundo real não se use algoritmos simples assim, também não são apenas humanos que tentam quebrar essas criptografias, algoritmos especializados também fazem esse trabalho sujo, então daí nasce a necessidade de tornar essas senhas mais seguras.

O salt consiste na adição de caracteres, palavras, termos ou mesmo números que dão aleatoriedade ao resultado da criptografia e ajuda a torná-lo mais complexo. Geralmente são adicionados antes da criptografia, e podem ser fixos ou aleatórios.

Levando em conta o mesmo algoritmo citado, vamos ao exemplo:

`Senha: 123456
Salt: 20170323
Senha+Salt:          12342017032356
Senha Criptografada: 65323071024321`

Você pode criar salts aleatórios, dinâmicos que sequer precisam ser armazenados,  Você pode usar dados do próprio registro para determinar um salt (data do cadastro, ou data de criação). Tudo isso ajuda a aumentar a aleatoriedade e assim ajuda a dificultar identificação do padrão usado para criptografar algo.

Comment: Usar dados do registro para sal não é de todo ruim, mas é importante que sejam os dados da última mudança de senha, não do cadastro do usuário ou algo assim. Muitos usuários reusam senhas, e se um sal usado numa senha anteriormente quebrada for usado de novo com a mesma senha, o hash resultante será idêntico. O ideal mesmo é que o sal seja aleatório, mas estritamente falando qualquer dado único serve (e ele não precisa ser secreto, embora se for simples escondê-lo, com certeza dá uma segurança adicional).

Comment: se o salt for aleatorio como vc vai verificar a senha novamente??... porque se foi aleatorio  a probabildiade de vc  gerar o mesmo salt para verifica se as hashs batem é minima