# HTML & PHP - código HTML simplesmente não lido

Tags: php, html, sql

Tenho seguinte código por parte do PHP não apresenta nenhum erro, a pagina aparece em branco e não mostra o código HTML.

```
<?php
include("config.php");
if($_GET['key'] && $_GET['reset'])
{
  $email=password_hash($_GET['key'],PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
  $pass=password_hash($_GET['reset'],PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
  $sql=mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT email, password FROM registo where email='$email' and password='$pass'");
  if(mysqli_num_rows($sql)==1)
  {
    ?>
<html>
    <form method="post" action="update_newpassword.php">
    <input type="hidden" name="email" value="<?php echo $email;?>">
    <p>Enter New password</p>
    <input type="password" name='password'>
    <input type="submit" name="submit_password">
    </form>
    </html>
    <?php

  }
}
?>
```

Comment: Coloque essas duas linhas no começo do script: `ini_set('dispaly_errors', true);error_reporting(E_ALL);` veja se aparece algum erro.

Comment: Não há nenhum erro. O que existe é um uso equivocado da criptografia. O `password_hash` até a versão 7.1 é somente BCrypt. Ele gera um salt diferente (e teoricamente único) para cada vez. Portanto quando você utiliza ele para dar o `INSERT` ele irá salvar `$(algo)$(dificuldate)$(salt [primerios 16 caracteres, salvo engano])(hash da senha)`. Por isso o `verify_password` funciona, porque gera a senha de entrada novamente com o mesmo salt e então compara. Porém fazer o que está fazendo, usando um `SELECT` é impossível, porque o novo `$email` será diferente do `$email` que está lá

Comment: mas o PHP nao apresenta nenhum erro, o HTML codigo simplesmente nao aparece!

Comment: a pagina aparece em branco

Comment: Aparece em branco porque não acha o SELECT, menos (ou mais) que uma linha. Crie um `else` no `if(mysqli_num_rows($sql)==1)` e verá isto. De um `var_dump(mysqli_num_rows($sql))`;

Comment: Está passando key e reset na url?

Comment: Inkeliz fiz o q vc disse e apareceu o seguinte: int(0)

Comment: Maurivan esse é o meu link: $link="<a href='http://unn-w17015779.newnumyspace.co.uk/reset.php?key=".$email."&reset=".$pass."'>Click To Reset password</a>";

Comment: @DianaMadeira Justamente, ele não encontra porque o BCrypt sempre gera uma hash diferente, se ele sempre gera algo diferente como quer acha o que é igual a ele?! Vou postar uma resposta explicando isso.

Comment: ok aguardo Inkeliz

Answer (score 5):

O problema é lógico e previsível pelo comportamento do BCrypt. Tentarei passar um básico do comportamento do BCrypt.

Mas, veja que fazer isto:

```
<?php

$senha = "a-mesma-senha";

echo password_hash($senha,PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
```

Retornará:

```
$2y$10$l1Ka5O0C9oYxyY./MvA5YOH1JBTjcY9qTefOLUrZMZ8R4H8kR3UmO
```

Mas, o mesmo código retornará:

```
$2y$10$J.eVvzGeh4FQh9uHb8Exz.U9jfn8hJhXs58bvdBYITkLfjLAJp0aK
```

E sem alterar nada também retorna:

```
$2y$10$VFXgZFjjRLqeQvGIdeAtiuQR8jt1x.6wiz/L4dSBWC5w8fUbWwgDu
```

[Veja você mesmo, clique em "Execute Code" várias vezes e sempre o resultado será diferente](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/77c9498c127aa1ca294cfabb6d4da05f6a5f0544)

---

Isto é auto-explicativo. Quando você faz o `INSERT` você insere por exemplo:

```
$2y$10$l1Ka5O0C9oYxyY./MvA5YOH1JBTjcY9qTefOLUrZMZ8R4H8kR3UmO
```

Mas quando você faz isto novamente você tenta procurar por, no `SELECT`:

```
$2y$10$VFXgZFjjRLqeQvGIdeAtiuQR8jt1x.6wiz/L4dSBWC5w8fUbWwgDu
```

Que obviamente são diferentes e você não irá acha-los.

Esse conjunto de códigos com uns `$` no meio representam:

```
$<algo>$<dificuldade>$<sal (22 caracteres)><senha (31 caracteres)>
```

Apenas a **titulo de curiosidade** e para que sabia como isto funciona observe que se fizer isto:

```
// Não utilize isto em produção!

// Gera o BCrypt
$hashUm = password_hash('senha', PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

// Obtem o salt da hash gerada (primeiros 22 caracteres após o último $):
$salt = substr(substr($hashUm, strrpos($hashUm, '$')), 1, 22);

// Gera um nova senha COM O MESMO SALT:
$hashDois = password_hash('senha', PASSWORD_DEFAULT, ['salt' => $salt]);


if($hashDois === $hashUm){
echo 'Funcionou';
}
```

**Não utilize o código acima por motivos óbvios de segurança.**

Porque o código acima funciona mesmo gerando duas vezes? Porque é o mesmo salt (a mesma dificuldade e o mesmo algoritmo), portanto a mesma hash será resultante, isto é como o `verify_password` funciona.

Isto é "exatamente" o que ocorre quando é usando o `password_verify()`, ele obtêm o salt da hash e então criptografa a entrada com o mesmo salt e verifica, porém logicamente com proteções contra side-channel e afins.

---

A diferença entre o BCrypt/PBKDF2/Argon2i/SCrypt (...) contra o SHA256, MD5, SHA-1 (...) é justamente que todos eles possuem ajuste de dificuldade e também um salt, o salt em especifico faz com que [senhas iguais não sejam iguais](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/179749/por-que-a-op%C3%A7%C3%A3o-salt-do-password-hash-foi-depreciada-no-php-7), [veja esta publicação também](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/185058/o-que-%C3%A9-salt-quando-se-trata-de-criptografia-de-senhas), como facilmente pode ver acima.

---

**Como resolver o problema:**

Simples, primeiro um valor deve ser fixo para ambos os lados, ele deve ser "texto-plano", não cifrado.

Por exemplo:

```
$tokenPlanoComum = unpack('H*', random_bytes(128))[1];

$tokenSecretoCliente = unpack('H*', random_bytes(32))[1];
$tokenSecretoBanco = password_hash($tokenSecretoCliente,PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
```

Você irá salvar no banco de dados a seguinte informação:

```
$tokenSecretoBanco 
$tokenPlanoComum
```

Você irá enviar para o cliente as informações:

```
$tokenPlanoComum
$tokenSecretoCliente
```

Depois para dar o `SELECT` você irá obter via o `$tokenPlanoComum`, dessa forma, por exemplo:

```
SELECT * FROM tabela WHERE tokenPlanoComum = "$tokenPlanoComum"
```

Então depois do SELECT compare a informação que o cliente enviou (do URL) com o do banco:

```
if(password_verify($_GET['tokenSecretoCliente'], $tabela['tokenSecretoBanco'])){
// Tudo certo!
}
```

Lembre-se de, se aplicável, definir um tempo de expiração, para impedir que seja possível utilizar o mesmo token depois de muito tempo gerado.

**Porque isto é eficiente?**

Se houver uma falha no seu sistema que permita obter as informações da tabela (exemplo um Read-Only SQL Injection), um deles está criptografado e somente o cliente tem a posse, por isso ainda estará seguro uma vez que será preciso de ambos corretos. ;)

**Porque isto funciona?**

Porque existe um ponto em comum onde é imutável e sempre será o mesmo para ambos os lados.

Comment: Inkeliz voce se alguma maneira até pode ter razão mas certamente não é isso que faz com que o meu código HTML aparece ou não, porque a minha duvida aqui foi isso, foi o fato de o codigo HTML não aparecer. eeu creio que o problema esta no if antes

Comment: @DianaMadeira, isto é óbvio. O `mysqli_num_rows` retorna a quantidades de linhas que a consulta do mysql obteve. Se o MySQL não consegue encontrar a informação resultará num `num_rows` com valor  `0`, afinal ele achou 0 linhas. O MySQL não irá encontrar pelo motivo que disse acima. Se ele retorna `0` ele será diferente de `1` e como consequência não irá aparecer o HTML. Presumi que saberia a utilidade o [`mysqli_num_rows`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/mysqli-result.num-rows.php), que é informar a quantidade de linhas obtidas pela consulta anterior. O motivo de ser `0`,  foi o que disse acima.

Comment: Resposta perfeita. Iria perguntar mais futuramente quando implantasse o meu sistema de recuperação e, por sorte, encontrei essa sua resposta. Totalmente funcional em meus testes. Obrigado!