# PHP - problemas com código para fazer reset de password

Tags: php, html, sql

Estou a tentar criar um link que é enviado para o utilizador para que possa fazer reset da password:

Tenho o seguinte código que envia o codigo para o usuario:

```
<?php
 include("config.php");
if(isset($_POST['submit_email']) && $_POST['email'])
{
    $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['email']);
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM registo WHERE email = '$email'";
    $r = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    $count = mysqli_num_rows($r);
    if($count == 1){
        $res = mysqli_fetch_assoc($r);
        $email=password_hash($res['email'],PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
        $pass=password_hash($res['password'],PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
        $link="<a href='http:****.php?key=".$email."&reset=".$pass."'>Click To Reset password</a>";
        $to = $res['email'];
        $subject = 'Reset Password';
        $message = 'Click On This Link to Reset Password '.$link;
        $headers = 'From: Galaxy books shop <**@gmail.com>' . "\r\n" .
                   'Reply-To: **@mail.com' . "\r\n" .
                   'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
        // Send email
        if(mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers)){
            echo "Your reset link has been sent to your email ";
        }else{
            echo "Failed to Recover your password, try again";
        }

    }else{
        echo "User name does not exist";
    }
}
?>
```

E depois tenho o código que supostamente deveria fazer com que o usuario crie uma nova pass:

```
<?php
include("config.php");
if($_GET['key'] && $_GET['reset'])
{
  $email=password_hash($_GET['key'],PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
  $pass=password_hash($_GET['reset'],PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
  $sql=mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT email, password FROM registo where email='$email' and password='$pass'");
  $count = mysqli_num_rows($sql);  
  if($count==1)
  {
    ?>
<html>
    <form method="post" action="update_newpassword.php">
    <input type="hidden" name="email" value="<?php echo $email;?>">
    <p>Enter New password</p>
    <input type="password" name='password'>
    <input type="submit" name="submit_password">
    </form>
    </html>
    <?php

  }
}
```

?>

O problema é que nada esta acontecer o link de fato é enviado mas ao clickar no link a página simplesmente aparece em Branco.

Comment: Checou qual o http status de retorno? Verificou se a variavel $email está conseguindo descriptografar? Provavelmente está em branco pq o $count deve estar retornando ZERO.

Comment: Seu código não tem nenhum erro, literalmente, o erro está na implementação do `password_hash`. Não vai funcionar porque nunca vai achar um `email` e `password` igual, simples assim, isso é BCrypt, com um salt sempre diferente. O `$count` irá retornar `0`, no segundo caso, quando não achar, [você já perguntou sobre isso](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/204633/html-php-c%C3%B3digo-html-simplesmente-n%C3%A3o-lido).

Comment: Inkeliz tem voce entao postar o meu codigo com as alteracoes que voce sugere pf?pois eu nao tou entendo.a outra resposta q vc deu foi mais teoria do que pratica e eu sinceramente nunca ouvi falar do que vc ta dizendo pois sou nova em PHP