# Como funciona o bcrypt?

Tags: segurança, hash, senhas, bcrypt

Não entendi muito bem o funcionamento do `salt` do [bcrypt](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bcrypt), num código em javascript (node):

```
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');
const saltRounds = 10;

async function init(plainPassword) {
    let salt = await bcrypt.genSalt(saltRounds);
    console.log(salt);

    let hashPassword = await bcrypt.hash(plainPassword, salt);
    console.log(hashPassword);

    let check = await bcrypt.compare(plainPassword, hashPassword);
    console.log(check);
}
init('cba');
```

Eu crio um salt e uso para criar o hash da senha, depois eu verifico a senha usando a função `compare`, porém nela não é passado o salt criado anteriormente, como então o bcrypt faz essa comparação, já que o valor do salt irá interferir no hash final da senha?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O `hashPassword` inclui o salt utilizado. Eu praticamente respondi isso [em outra questão](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/204641/15089), mas como a pergunta não era especificamente sobre isso, então acho que posso responder aqui também.

*A mesma forma que "funciona no Node" é mesma que funciona em qualquer lugar, já que ele implementa o mesmo BCrypt.*

---

O BCrypt é determinístico. Por esse motivo terá o mesmo resultado se for usando o mesmo salt, assim como qualquer KDF existente. No BCrypt possui três parâmetros:

- Custo computacional.
- Salt.
- Senha.

> Existem outras funções de derivações (KDFs) que possuem outros parâmetros de entrada. O Argon2, por exemplo, tem parâmetros de custos individuais (para memoria, iteração e etc), parâmetros parâmetros de comprimento de saída. Por outro lado, o HKDF não possui custo computacional, por não ser destinado a senhas, mas possui comprimento de hash, do resultado, flexível.

Como resultado terá:

- "Hash".

Entretanto, os dois primeiros valores são públicos, no caso do BCrypt. Por isso, o próprio BCrypt utiliza um formato, similar ao [Modular Crypt Format](http://passlib.readthedocs.io/en/stable/modular_crypt_format.html#overview), onde:

```
${Algoritmo}${Custo}${Salt}{Hash}
```

Dessa forma a hash está incluída em valores que possibilitam comparar a mesma hash, já que conhecemos o algoritmo, o custo, o salt e o resultado esperado.

---

Um pequeno teste, com um resultado de:

```
$2b$10$111111111111111111111u1Fg3CCqE4CYDkm0w0C9gxJ.HpXSNHlS
```

Você pode obter o algoritmo, o custo, o salt e a "hash esperada", portanto:

```
    let resultado = '$2b$10$111111111111111111111u1Fg3CCqE4CYDkm0w0C9gxJ.HpXSNHlS';

    let algo = resultado.substring(1, 3);
    let custo = resultado.substring(4, 6);
    let salt = resultado.substring(7, 29);
```

Então basta fazer o `bcrypt.hash` e você poderá comparar o valor, normalmente:

```
const crypto = require('crypto');
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');

async function init(plainPassword) {
    let resultado = '$2b$10$111111111111111111111u1Fg3CCqE4CYDkm0w0C9gxJ.HpXSNHlS';

    let algo = resultado.substring(1, 3);
    let custo = resultado.substring(4, 6);
    let salt = resultado.substring(7, 29);

    let hash = await bcrypt.hash(plainPassword, '$' + algo + '$' + custo + '$' + salt);

    console.log(crypto.timingSafeEqual(Buffer.from(hash), Buffer.from(resultado)));
}

init('cba');
```

Veja que não existe nenhum `bcrypt.compare`, o `crypto.timingSafeEqual` faz o mesmo que o `===`, porém é seguro contra timing-attack. É basicamente isso que o `bcrypt.compare` faz, quando você inclui o `hashPassword` ele já tem os dados necessários. :)

Comment: Então, nesse caso, qual é a função do `salt`?

Comment: @GuilhermeCostamilam Impedir que uma mesma senha tenha o mesmo resultado. Se você tem KDF(1,1), KDF(1, 2), KDF(1, 3) terão resultados distintos, mesmo que o "1" esteja em ambas. Isso impede ataques de pré-computação, já que para pre-computar o resultado de uma senha X terá que computar todas possibilidades de SALT com X.

Comment: Eu estava pensando em fazer algo como `bcrypt.hash(plainPassword, salt+systemSalt)` sendo `systemSalt` um salt constante no sistema, faz diferença? Ou `bcrypt.hash(salt+plainPassword+systemSalt, salt)`? Alguma delas pode aumentar a segurança?

Comment: Isso se chama "pepper". Não há ganhos significativos na segurança, no BCrypt isso é pior, porque o salt é limitado a 16 bytes. Em outros KDF (Argon2) você pode ter salt maiores, então poderá ainda ter 32 bytes de salt e mais 32 bytes de pepper, por exemplo. Você colocar um salt junto a senha é uma catástrofe completa. O Bcrypt apenas suporta senhas de até 72 bytes, então usar 16 bytes reduzirá a possibilidade para, no máximo, 56 bytes. Se ainda for adicionar como prefixo, dependendo do tamanho acabará por inutilizar a senha. Use o algoritmo como ele foi proposto, ou use um outro algoritmo.

Comment: @GuilhermeCostamilam O "pepper" faz sentido se você estiver fisicamente isolado, por exemplo um banco de dados num servidor, o web em outro e talvez um outro HSM. Dessa forma comprometer um não dará todas as informações, mas no BCrypt isso é mais complicado, por falta de espaço.

Comment: Uma dúvida, o `saltRouds`, quanto maior o número maior o tempo/recursos que levará para criar a senha, correto? Mas isso aumenta a segurança para compensar? Qual seria mais ou menos o valor ideal que equilibre entre os dois?

Comment: Sim. Isso faz ser mais difícil de achar a senha através da hash, porém mais fácil de fazer um DoS, por usar mais recursos do servidor também. O ideal depende de quão frequente exige as senhas e qual o tempo tolerado de resposta e também do hardware. Normalmente recomendam até 1 segundo ou até 500ms. Defina o custo mais alto onde o seu servidor é capaz de atender dentro deste tempo, usualmente algo entre 14 até 17.