# Qual é o algoritmo de geração de hash que o Laravel utiliza?

Tags: php, laravel, hash

Por padrão o Laravel já vem com um sistema de autenticação pré-pronto, porém, alguém saberia me falar qual é o algoritmo *default* que este *framework* utiliza para geração de *hash* e qual sua versão?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Segundo a [documentação](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/hashing), para este tipo de tarefa, é usado o [BCrypt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bcrypt), o que vai de encontro de uma [pergunta aqui sobre senhas seguras](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/2402/101). Exemplo:

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
class UpdatePasswordController extends Controller {
    /**
     * Update the password for the user.
     *
     * @param  Request  $request
     * @return Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request) {
        // Validate the new password length...
        $request->user()->fill([
            'password' => Hash::make($request->newPassword)
        ])->save();
    }
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/Algorithm/SecurePassword.php).