# Utilizar de Hash, sem adicionar uma cadeia Salt a senha, pode tornar a senha vulnerável?

Tags: hash, senhas, salt

A pouco tempo precisava descobrir qual *hash* havia sido utilizado para salvar a senhas no banco de forma que as mesmas não fossem salvas direto de acordo com o que o usuário lança no momento de seu cadastro. Pesquisando encontrei o seguinte [site](http://hashtoolkit.com/generate-hash/), que se você sabe a senha inicial você consegue ver os resultados que as *hash's* vão gerar em cima dessa senha. isso me pareceu de certa forma vulnerável pois assim que eu descobri qual *Hash* havia sido utilizada, e como eu tenho acesso acesso ao banco onde as senha ficam salvas, bastou que eu comparasse o que estava armazenado no banco com o que o site me gerava e assim descobri qual *Hash* havia sido utilizado.

Minha questão é:

Até onde utilizar uma cadeia **salt** na senha original auxilia para que a senha seja ainda mais segura, pois seria necessário além de acessar o banco e ter acesso as senhas seria necessário saber qual cadeia **salt** foi utilizada, tornando assim mais difícil descobrir qual a senha original cadastrada pelos usuários.

[Link para conteúdo sobre **Salt**](https://code.tutsplus.com/pt/tutorials/understanding-hash-functions-and-keeping-passwords-safe--net-17577)

Comment: Uai, você mesmo já respondeu sua duvida rs => **necessário além de acessar o banco e ter acesso as senhas seria necessário saber qual cadeia salt foi utilizada**

Comment: Minha questão é, se realmente faz diferença utilizar uma cadeia Salt em cima da senha original antes de aplicar o Hash, pois hoje em dia é aplicado uma hash em cima da senha inicial cadastrada e já é salva no banco direto, isso pode ser algo vulnerável

Comment: Qual algoritmo está usando? SHA1? SHA512?

Comment: @PauloSérgioDuff SHA 256

Comment: É uma boa pergunta esta sua. Creio que todos os pontos levantados já estejam respondidos com detalhes em [Como fazer hash de senhas de forma segura?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/2402/como-fazer-hash-de-senhas-de-forma-segura),

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Não existe um ponto em que seja totalmente seguro usar um algoritmo de *hash*.**

Um problema é o ataque de dicionário em cima de *hashes*. Serviços como https://crackstation.net/ podem facilmente quebrar um *hash* como, por exemplo, o SHA256. Restringir que o usuário use senhas complexas para driblar isso (com caracteres, números, letras maiúsculas...) pode não ser tão fácil, visto que a maioria dos problemas de segurança vem por fatores humanos, como o *phishing*, que consegue uma taxa de 45% de conversão [segundo a empresa de segurança ReturnPath](https://returnpath.com/pt-br/blog/gestao-de-risco-e-os-desafios-da-seguranca-no-varejo-online/).O que te passa uma responsabilidade maior na hora da segurança. Um outro problema ao usar SHA256, deixa vulnerável ao ataque por [processamento por força bruta](https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/faq.passwords.php#faq.passwords.fasthash) (isso vale para algoritmos ultrapassados como MD5 e SHA1). Portanto, é 'falsa' a ideia de que usar *salt* deixa o algoritmo mais seguro por si só (no sentido de existir opção mais segura). No caso do seu problema, um *SQL injection* poderia revelar informações do banco de dados para comparação do *salt*.

Isso não quer dizer que não existem opções. Algumas delas:

- 1) Forçar um cadastro de senhas complexas. Se o escopo da aplicação
  permitir.
- 2) Introduzir token dentro do hash (caso não seja possível a opção
  1).
- 3) Usar [bcrypt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bcrypt). O algoritmo bluefish permite a criação de parâmetro
  de processamento para aumentar a complexidade do hash.