# O que difere um FPGA para um CPU?

Tags: criptografia, cpu

Estava vendo algumas publicações sobre o algoritmo criptográfico BLAKE, que foi um dos finalistas da competição do SHA-3, *cujo o vencedor foi Keccak*.

Enfim, em trecho específico do livro "The Hash Function BLAKE", logo no inicio, diz:

> Keccak offers acceptable performance in software, and excellent performance in hardware.

[Fonte 1](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=nhPmBQAAQBAJ&pg=PR7&lpg=PR7&dq=Keccak+%22offers+acceptable+performance+in+software,+and+excellent+performance+in+hardware%22) [Fonte 2 (Original, pela NIST)](http://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/ir/2012/NIST.IR.7896.pdf)

> NIST could just as easily have stated that BLAKE offers excellent performance in software and acceptable performance in hardware; nowhere did NIST suggest that hardware is more important than software

[Fonte](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=nhPmBQAAQBAJ&pg=PR7&lpg=PR7&dq=NIST+could+just+as+easily+have+stated+that+BLAKE+offers+excellent+performance+in+software+and+acceptable+performance+in+hardware;+nowhere+did+NIST+suggest+that+hardware+is+more+important+than+software)

A minha questão foi pesquisar por como algo consegue ser rápido em hardware e lento em software e principalmente o contrário. Todos os locais que encontrei falam sobre *um tal de* FPGA (e também ASIC), isto também está presente no texto da NIST, na competição do SHA-3:

> **3.2 Performance**
>
> NIST was fortunate to have a great depth of performance data on the five finalists that could also be compared with the performance data of the SHA-2 algorithms. This data included software implementations on many different kinds of Central Processing Units (CPUs), and hardware implementations in both Field Programmable Gate Arrays (FPGAs) and Application Specific Integrated Circuits (ASICs). All this data made simple comparisons very difficult; most algorithms excelled on some platforms and lagged on others. However, a few patterns emerged from the performance data, which affected NIST’s decision

---

Sabemos então que existem CPUs, FPGAs e ASICs. Isso também já foi mencionado em [outras respostas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/2402/como-fazer-hash-de-senhas-de-forma-segura/2405#2405), que [única coisa que encontrei no SO](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=FPGA), em "Um atacante com GPU ou FPGA pode querer fazer isso, mas terá dificuldade.".

---

Qual é a diferença da execução em um CPU e em um FPGA? Como é possível *algo* ser mais rápido em software, CPU, do que num FPGA? Quais seriam as dificuldades de um FPGA ser tão rápido quanto o CPU?

Comment: **Acho** que é fora de escopo. Eu gostaria que fosse aceita e me interesso numa resposta, inclusive deixei meu voto positivo.

Comment: Não sou muito conhecedor dos algoritmos de criptografia, mas acho que é possível que uma implementação seja mais rápida em software quando o cálculo é essencialmente sequencial. A FPGA trabalha naturalmente com paralelismo, enquanto a CPU já é projetada para receber comandos sequenciais.

Answer (score 3):

A principal diferença entre um **CPU** (Central Processing Unity) e um **FPGA** (Field Programmable Gate Array) é a flexibilidade na construção.

Um processador comum (CPU) processa instruções a nível do sistema operacional, e sua montagem é principiada em entender o *Machine Code* universal do da arquitetura particular do processador. Já um FPGA, não é necessário ter um interpretador de instruções universal, ele pode ser moldado dinamicamente para um fim específico, sendo assim, processando somente um algoritmo, tipo de instrução, etc.

Quando citamos em processamento de *hash* por softwares, lembramos que as instruções escritas no determinado algoritmo sempre passarão pelo **CPU**, no entanto, irá considerar o tempo de resposta da velocidade do mesmo, do sistema operacional, e todos os outros fatores que também utilizam o CPU para demais operações rotinárias.

Diferente de software, o processamento por hardware dedicado a aquele algoritmo, no caso um **FPGA** devidamente escrito, poderá ter um desempenho superior em relação ao **CPU**, uma vez que o FPGA é dedicado a somente aquele tipo de processamento, ele só irá esperar um tipo de entrada, e dele sairá somente um tipo de saída.

Um chip FPGA pode ser consistente de vários blocos de processamento (núcleos), e são configurados e manipulados pelo usuário. Portanto, ele pode ser manipulado para executar operações uniformes num curto período de tempo. Na maior parte das vezes, um FPGA bem configurado sempre é mais rápido que um processador convencional.

Na criptografia, o uso dedicado de determinado algoritmo dentro de um FPGA pode sim aumentar sua performance exponencialmente (quando bem configurado, também considerando a qualidade do chip), pois o chip estará adequadamente configurado a processar as instruções daquele algoritmo. Algoritmos para FPGA são escritos em [VHDL](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/VHDL).

[Aqui está uma implementação do AES escrita em VHDL.](https://github.com/pnvamshi/Hardware-Implementation-of-AES-VHDL) Você pode pegar este código e configurar no seu próprio FPGA.

## tl;dr

Por resumo, o FPGA é um processador de instruções dedicados a um (ou mais) algoritmos, escritos pelo próprio usuário. E por conta disso, ele processará as informações mais rapidamente do que um CPU convencional, como *hashing* de informações, por exemplo.

**FPGA** são moldáveis e flexíveis. **CPU** é universal, tratará qualquer instrução de `Machine Code`, e logo, por agregar tudo, terá uma performance inferior em relação ao FPGA, **isso quando estiver comparando um algoritmo dedicado à ambos.**

> Qual é a diferença da execução em um CPU e em um FPGA?

A mesma explicada acima.

> Como é possível algo ser mais rápido em software, CPU, do que num FPGA?

Uma má-implementação pode sim ser mais lenta do que num CPU em certos casos. Nisso, é bom considerar:

- o processador que está comparando (a velocidade, qualidade, tamanho de cache);
- a qualidade do chip FGPU e tamanho de instrução do mesmo;
- como o algoritmo foi escrito por parte de software (CPU);
- como o algoritmo foi escrito por parte de hardware (FGPU).

Em relação ao que foi citado acima, é uma questão de ambiente e desenvolvimento. É como perguntar como um algoritmo escrito na linguagem X pode ser melhor que na linguagem Y.

> Quais seriam as dificuldades de um FPGA ser tão rápido quanto o CPU?

FPGA e CPU têm propósitos diferentes um do outro. O CPU visa ser algo central, onde todas instruções sejam passadas por ele. O FPGA visa ser limitado a somente um propósito, escrito pelo usuário. E nisso se enquadra também na questão do ambiente de utilização, bem como o porquê de sua utilização.

---

Mais informações e *benchmarks*:

- [GPU vs FPGA Performance Comparison](http://www.bertendsp.com/pdf/whitepaper/BWP001_GPU_vs_FPGA_Performance_Comparison_v1.0.pdf)
- [Computing Performance Benchmarks among CPU, GPU, and FPGA](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/cbec/d8cfb5264f8b36dee412c5980e3305c996e6.pdf)

Comment: Aí passa da FPGA para um ASIC e tem ainda mais ganhos em performance :D

Comment: Não cheguei a pesquisar sobre o ASIC, @AndersonCarlosWoss. Vou dar uma lida sobre :)

Comment: A FPGA é, por definição, (re)programável e isso faz com que prejudique o tempo de resposta dada a arquitetura dela. O roteamento é feito a partir da sintetização do VHDL e pode ser otimizado, enquanto o ASIC é um circuito estático destinado àquele finalidade. Quando é algo muito crítico, o processo natural é utilizarem a FPGA em tempo de desenvolvimento, por ser reprogramável e quanto atingir resultados satisfatórios, gera-se a máscara de circuito para produzir um ASIC. Os próprios processadores hoje são produzidos assim (Intel pelo menos).

Comment: É bom usar ambos então para certo desenvolvimento. Uma vez que o ASIC é involátil, pode-se usar o FPGA para programar e testar os scripts VHDL no FPGA antes de queimar diretamente no ASIC. E então, depois que compilar o código dentro do ASIC, terá um algoritmo rodando num chip super rápido e dedicado. ;D

Comment: Isso, exatamente.

Comment: Dei o +1, mas há ainda "algo" que faz o "FPGA ser lento". O BLAKE, diferente do Keccak, é baseado em ARX (Addition/Rotation/XOR) e o que encontrei mais perto de responder é "The time needed for a modular addition of the natural word size of a general-purpose computer is often as fast as bitwise logic operations. In hardware, this is not the case: word-length bitwise logic is faster than addition with its carry propagation delays. Therefore, the fastest hash function on a general-purpose computer is not necessarily the fastest hash function in hardware.".

Comment: A comparação feita para determinar "lento" ou "rápido" foi comparar o "throughput/area" e o "energy-consumption-per-message-bit". Uma das coisas é que, a construção do Keccak pode ser paralelizada, o que beneficia o FPGA, já o BLAKE não pode. O que eu ainda não encontrei claramente é: "o que" beneficia um FPGA e "o que" beneficia um CPU. Eu acho que um FPGA será mais rápido que um CPU, comparando um único algoritmo. Mas, comparando vários (como BLAKE e Keccak), um deles tem melhor performance em FPGA (Keccak) e outro (BLAKE) tem melhor performance em CPU, o problema é: porque isso ocorre?!

Comment: @Inkeliz isso pode te ajudar a esclarecer sua dúvida. Não vou tentar explicar o que entendi porque é bem superficial, mas espero que tenha o que procura: https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/31674/what-advantages-does-keccak-sha-3-have-over-blake2

Comment: @Inkeliz Parece ser o que [comentei lá em 2017](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/212293/o-que-difere-um-fpga-para-um-cpu/400383?noredirect=1#comment435556_212293). O que beneficia o uso da FPGA é justamente o paralelismo das operações. Ela não trabalha tão bem para operações sequenciais pois há um custo muito grande por parte do hardware para garantir a sequência correta.

Comment: No mestrado eu desenvolvi um modem de comunicação fibra óptica com FPGA e uma parte do receptor consistia em calcular a transformada de Fourier do sinal de entrada. Implementei o algoritmo sequencial para tal e tive uma queda enorme de desempenho, pois eu precisava projetar as rotas e gerenciar o tempo de propagação de cada sinal dentro da FPGA para garantir a sequência das operações. Isso resulta em um uso "abusivo" de flip-flops e multiplexadores que elevam bastante o tempo de resposta final, justamente pelo tempo de propagação e resposta desses componentes.

Comment: @Inkeliz uma causa provável para que certo algoritmo se comporte melhor num CPU do que um FPGA é considerar que ambos são arquiteturas totalmente diferentes, e um algoritmo pode ter sido escrito especialmente a aquela arquitetura daquele processador. Logo, ela será otimizada a aquele ambiente, e não ao outro.