# Esconder senha do banco de dados

Tags: banco-de-dados, asp.net, segurança, web.config

Boa Tarde,

Eu tenho alguns sites cuja senha do banco de dados, eu armazeno numa string de conexão, no web.config.

Qualquer programador que tenha acesso ao ftp da hospedagem, pode ler o arquivo web.config e ver a senha do banco de dados.

Existe algum forma de se esconder a senha do banco de dados?

Comment: Recomendo a leitura de [Como fazer hash de senhas de forma segura?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/2402/como-fazer-hash-de-senhas-de-forma-segura)

Answer (score 2):

Você pode criptografar seu arquivo web.config com um componente chamado aspnet_regiis.

Para criptografar as seções  e  do arquivo web.config.

Em um editor de texto, abra o arquivo web.config para seu aplicativo.
Se você não tiver um arquivo Web.config para seu aplicativo ASP.NET, abra um editor de texto, copie a configuração de exemplo em um novo arquivo e, em seguida, salvar o arquivo no seu diretório de aplicativo ASP.NET sistema autônomo web.config.

Certifique-se de que que há um elemento filho  e um elemento filho  para o elemento , conforme mostrado no exemplo o seguir.

```
<configuration>
   <connectionStrings>
      <add name="SqlServices" connectionString="Data Source=localhost;Integrated Security=SSPI;Initial Catalog=Northwind;" />
   </connectionStrings>

   <system.web>

     <machineKey validationKey="D61B3C89CB33A2F1422FF158AFF7320E8DB8CB5CDA1742572A487D94018787EF42682B202B746511891C1BAF47F8D25C07F6C39A104696DB51F17C529AD3CABE"
       decryptionKey="FBF50941F22D6A3B229EA593F24C41203DA6837F1122EF17" />

   </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Feche o arquivo web.config.

Na prompt de comando, altere o diretório para o diretório do .NET Framework versão 2.0, digitando o seguinte comando:
cd \WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\Framework\v2.0.*

No prompt de comando, execute a ferramenta Aspnet_regiis.exe com as seguintes opções:
A opção -pe e a sequência de caracteres "connectionStrings" para criptografar o elemento connectionStrings do arquivo web.config para seu aplicativo.
A opção -app e o nome do seu aplicativo.
Por exemplo, o comando a seguir criptografa a seção  do arquivo web.config para um aplicativo chamado MyApplication.
aspnet_regiis -pe "connectionStrings" -app "/MyApplication"

Repita a etapa anterior para o elemento filo  do elemento ,conforme mostrado no exemplo a seguir:
aspnet_regiis -pe "system.web/machineKey" -app "/MyApplication"
Não feche a janela do prompt de comando.

Abra web.config e então visualize o conteúdo criptografado.
O conteúdo será semelhante ao seguinte exemplo arquivo web.config.

Para mais informações, o site oficial da Microsoft pode lhe dar mais informações! 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/dtkwfdky(v=vs.100).aspx