# Faz sentido armazenar o salt de uma senha com o próprio hash?

Tags: banco-de-dados, segurança, criptografia, hash, salt

Espiando tabelas em um banco de dados de um certo produto, me deparei com uma estrutura semelhante a esta:

```
[LocalUsers]
UserId           Integer
PasswordHash     Byte[]
Salt             Byte[]
```

Se um intruso obtém esta lista, é o suficiente para ele aplicar técnicas de descoberta, tal qual como se fossem *hashes* limpos (sem *salt*)?

Pergunta de apoio:
[Como fazer hash de senhas de forma segura?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/2402/como-fazer-hash-de-senhas-de-forma-segura)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sem problema algum. A função do "sal" existe para evitar colisões de senhas iguais ou de *hashes* que resultem iguais. A sua função não é estabelecer um segredo, é apenas para evitar descobrir uma senha por coincidência.

Conforme mostra na pergunta *linkada* e outras sobre o assunto é importante que ela seja aleatória e suficiente para evitar duplicidade de interpretação.

A força do *hash* deve ser suficiente para o caso de comprometimento do banco de dados de senhas, não dê essa responsabilidade para o *salt*.

A força é algo geral, é a dificuldade de quebrá-la. Por exemplo, existe uma nova que é mais segura do que as existentes quando aquela pergunta foi respondida: https://github.com/P-H-C/phc-winner-argon2. Havendo invasão o *salt* influencia nada, por isso não precisa protegê-lo, ele serve para combater outros tipos de ataques, não para evitar que um servidor invadido roube senhas, para esse caso o *hash* deve ser o melhor possível, é isso que está na resposta.

Se não colocar ali, colocará onde? Em outra tabela? Dá no mesmo para a segurança. Em outro banco de dados? Muda nada. Em outro servidor? Aí ajuda só um pouco, mas cria uma complicação para o software.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Você citou `força do hash`. O que seria exatamente isso? Número de iterações? Colocando de outra forma: Havendo um invasor o hash e salt de uma dada senha, o que ainda torna esse hash mais forte do que um simples hash sem salt?

Comment: A força é algo geral, é a dificuldade de quebrá-la. Por exemplo, existe uma nova que é mais segura do que as existentes quando aquela pergunta foi respondida: https://github.com/P-H-C/phc-winner-argon2. Havendo invasão o *salt* não influencia nada, por isso não precisa protegê-lo, ele serve para combater outros tipos de ataques, não para evitar que um servidor invadido roube senhas, para este caso o *hash* deve ser o melhor possível, é isso que está na resposta.

Comment: "...ele serve para combater outros tipos de ataques". Beleza, isso que eu queria saber. Obrigado