# Descobrir senha de usuário através de Select ou View?

Tags: sql, view

Estou gerindo uma *BD* que foi feita por um desenvolvedor que criou uma tabela de operadores, acontece que ele já não se encontra no mundo dos vivos.

Como descobrir a senha de um usuário através de uma tabela ou de uma *View* utilizando `SELECT * FROM`?

Comment: Depende da estrutura da tabela e de algum possível uso de criptografia. Se ele usou um hash para esconder a senha, e esse hash for 1-way, o máximo que você resgata é o hash da senha. Também pode sofrer alguma outra alteração caso sejam usados sais e temperos

Comment: A senha está aberta ou criptografada?

Comment: Leitura útil: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/2405/64969

Comment: Você pode aceitar a resposta clicando no ✔ no lado esquerdo da mesma.

Answer (score 2):

Se as senhas estiverem encriptadas então será muito difícil de conseguir de as conseguir ler, uma forma de resolução neste caso seria ter acesso ao projeto ou código, onde é gerada a criptografia das senhas.

Por outro lado se não tiverem nenhum tipo de criptografia as senhas, bastará um `select` para retornar tudo o que precisa, pode usar os exemplos abaixo para consulta a sua BD e os campos desejados.

Para ver todos os campos e registos de uma tabela na BD:

```
SELECT * FROM nome_tabela;
```

Para consultar todos os registos de um determinado campo de uma tabela:

```
SELECT nome_campo FROM nome_tabela;
```

Se pretender a pass de um determinado utilizador pode fazer assim:

```
SELECT * FROM nome_tabela WHERE nome='ze';
```

Ou

```
SELECT pass FROM nome_tabela WHERE nome='ana';
```

Alguma coisa onde possa ajudar avise, pode ainda consultar mais informação aqui [MYSQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html) ou aqui [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select.asp), sobre usar `SELECT` em consultas ao BD.

Comment: Como percebido pelo Bigown no [comentário dele](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/236658/descobrindo-senha-do-usuario-atreves-de-um-select-from-nome-tabela-ou-atreves#comment484444_236658) se a senha sofrer criptografia, então o máximo que se resgata é o valor criptografado.

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado Sim tem razão no entanto não foi mencionado na pergunta, caso sofre pode editar a resposta

Comment: caso sofra criptografia é mais provável que o valor seja não recuperável. Como a pergunta deixa muitos aspectos em aberto, acho que é relevante levantar essas possibilidades

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado a não ser que tenho acesso ao projeto ou código por onde passa e é gerado as pass..