# Recuperar senha em PHP

Tags: php

Fiz um sistema simples para recuperar senha. O sistema está funcionando normalmente, mas quando o usuário clica no email de confirmação, o email dele aparece na URI, o que faço? Eis o código:

Este é o formulário html:

```
<section class="recipiente margem-topo-100">
    <form action="recuperar_por_email.php" method="post" class="coluna">
      <input type="text" name="recuperar-senha" placeholder="Insira seu email">
      <button class="icones icone-enviar"></button>
    </form>
  </section>
```

Este é o código que faz o envio do email e cria as variáveis que utilizo:

```
<?php

  require_once "PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoLoad.php";
  require_once "interno/conecta.php";
  require_once "interno/funcoes.php";


  $recupera = $_POST['recuperar-senha'];
  $link = "http://localhost/toqve/recuperar.php?recupera=".$recupera;

  $mail = new PHPMailer();

  $mail->IsSMTP();
  $mail->isHTML(true);
  $mail->CharSet = 'utf-8';
  $mail->Host = 'mx1.weblink.com.br';
  $mail->Port = 587;
  $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
  $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
  $mail->Username = 'cadastro@dalvz.com.br';
  $mail->Password = '*********';
  $mail->setFrom("cadastro@dalvz.com.br", "daLvz");
  $mail->FromName = 'daLvz';
  $mail->Subject = "Recuperar senha";

  $mensagem = "Clique <a href=".$link.">aqui</a> para recuperar sua senha. 

  $mail->Body = $mensagem;
  $mail->AltBody = "Conteudo do email em texto";

  $mail->addAddress($recupera);

  if($mail->Send()) {

    header("Location: confirmacao.php");
  } else {

    echo "Erro ao enviar email". $mail->ErrorInfo;
  }
```

Esta é a página que aparece quando o usuário clica no email recebido:

```
<?php

  require_once "cabecalho.php";
  require_once "interno/conecta.php";
  require_once "interno/funcoes.php";
  $recupera = $_GET['recupera'];
?>

<section class="recipiente margem-topo-100">

  <form class="coluna" action="sucesso.php" method="post" >
    <input type="text" name="recupera" value="<?=$recupera?>">
    <input type="password" name="senha" placeholder="insira uma nova senha">
    <button class="icones icone-enviar"></button>
  </form>
</section>
```

Alguém pode me ajudar? Obrigado!

Comment: Faltam ai algumas `"` como pode ver pelo highlight do código. Confirme se tem assim no seu código ou se ficou assim apenas na pergunta

Comment: Não estou vendo onde falta não, mas asseguro que o meu código está funcionando. O único problema mesmo é que o email do usuário está vindo na URI depois que o usuário clica no link que vai para ele por email. Isso que estou precisando mudar. Mas obrigado pela observação @Isac

Comment: Veja esta parte do código: `$mensagem = "Clique <a href=".$link.">aqui</a> para recuperar sua senha. 

  $mail->Body = $mensagem;`. Note como a `$mensagem` não tem o `"` de fecho

Comment: Sim, verdade, mas foi na hora que eu fui adaptar a pergunta aqui para o fórum. Aqui estou fechando.. É que esqueci de colocar

Comment: Não relacionado à dúvida, mas extremamente relevante: senhas não devem ser recuperáveis. O que se faz usualmente é fornecer um link para que o usuário crie uma senha nova com base em um token. Se sua senha é recuperável por um usuário, ela é vulnerável a ataques em caso de roubo de dados, uma falha clássica de segurança. Salvo raras exceções (e a sua situação não parece ser uma delas) senhas devem ser armazenadas de maneira irreversível. [Veja aqui alguns conceitos sobre armazenamento de senhas de maneira segura](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/2402/70)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Problema

O problema do sistema que tem é que qualquer pessoa pode recuperar a password de outra desde que saiba o email dessa pessoa e o URI que o site utiliza para recuperações.

Se eu quisesse alterar a password do `joao@gmail.com` bastaria navegar até `http://localhost/toqve/recuperar.php?recupera=joao@gmail.com` que conseguia faze-lo mesmo não sendo o joão.

### Solução

Uma solução bastante melhor e mais robusta é gerar um *token* que fica associado a um email numa tabela. Algo que pode seguir a seguinte estrutura:

```
token                                  | email          | datahora
cf9186069dd09f16c959f70f1735c91b48549b | joao@gmail.com | 2017-10-07 12:00:00
```

Nesta estrutura o token tem que ser sempre único e por isso pode ficar como chave primaria da tabela, e o email assumi que era uma chave estrangeira para a tabela de usuários. Pode também ser um `id` se for essa a chave que tem definida na tabela de usuários.

O token passa a ser gerado dinamicamente no momento em que a tentativa de recuperação é feita. Este padrão de tokens é visível no próprio reset de password do StackOverflow:

```
https://stackoverflow.com/account/recover?recoveryToken=miA1WGREQDlAQDGRyUw%3d%3d%7cae52238c59a755ddd2faff86b2b2f91037048839582aa4cc88e709ASD02a4512c
```

<sup>Tirado de uma recuperação que já fiz aqui no stackoverflow (troquei alguns caracteres no token)</sup>

O token pode ser gerado de muitas formas e já deve envolver noções de criptografia para ser seguro. Uma forma simplificada de o gerar em PHP seria utilizando a função [`random_bytes`](https://secure.php.net/random_bytes) e [`bin2hex`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.bin2hex.php):

```
$token = bin2hex(random_bytes(50)); //tamanho de 50 bytes
```

Existem outras alternativas tais como [`openssl_random_pseudo_bytes`](https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.openssl-random-pseudo-bytes.php).

### Passos adicionais

O link tem agora que incluir o token gerado, e é necessário criar um novo registo na tabela de recuperações no banco de dados. Como a tabela tem data e hora, pode e deve definir um tempo máximo para recuperação por motivos de segurança, obrigando a pessoa a fazer uma nova recuperação se já tiver passado do tempo limite definido por si.

Uma vez que as recuperações ficam registadas no sistema, consegue-as consultar e potencialmente detetar abusos.

Comment: Resposta muito boa!