# Permitir ou não permitir espaços das extremidades em senhas?

Tags: segurança, ux

O [@dvd](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/8063/dvd) [respondeu sobre validação de senhas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/272337/64969) em JavaScript. Em sua resposta, ele sugeriu remover espaços das extremidades na hora de validar o tamanho:

> É interessante [para validar o tamanho da senha] também, eliminar espaços em branco nas bordas da string com o método `.trim()`

Discutimos brevemente sobre o assunto, mas achei o campo dos comentários muito superficial para isso. Então, pergunto:

- Devemos ou não devemos permitir senhas com espaçamento nas extremidades?
- Devemos considerar espaços das extremidades como indicador de força/comprimento da senha?

Pergunto isso porque, até onde me consta, o ideal seria [armazenar a senha de modo irrecuperável](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/2402/64969) porém verificável. E sendo assim, algoritmos de hash apenas fariam operações matemáticas com os bytes e eu teria que (sem as aspas)

```
"pizza de bacon"
```

é uma senha com hash distinto de (também sem as aspas)

```
"pizza de bacon  "
```

Então qual seria a vantagem de proibir ou permitir a existência de espaços nas extremidades das senhas?

Comment: Acho que isso é muito relativo. Vai depender do programador. Acho muito capenga uma pessoa colocar espaços nas extremidades da senha. Parece coisa de quem não conhece internet ou sistemas de senhas. E mesmo assim, a maioria dos sistemas já informam como deve ser a senha: "primeira letra maiúscula, deve conter pelo menos 1 número etc"..

Comment: A própria NIST que antes recomendava uma senha "cantante e dançante" voltou atrás: https://www.passwordping.com/surprising-new-password-guidelines-nist/ ; xkcd já falava que senha forte é senha de alta entropia faz muito tempo: https://xkcd.com/936/ ; então, sim, permitir distintos caracteres influenciam na senha, e isso deveria incluir espaço, sem falar que espaços aumentam o tamanho da senha e, portanto, o conjunto possibilidade para ser quebrado em força bruta. Limitar não ter espaços nos extremos diminui sub-exponencialmente o espaço de busca

Comment: Vale ressaltar que eu não sugeri remover espaços nas extremidades por causa da senha, foi apenas para contagem do tamanho da string.

Comment: @dvd verdade, não tinha percebido isso antes. Preciso reformular a pergunta, vou ver o que consigo rapidamente

Comment: Se o usuário digitar 6 espaços em branco, seria validado a senha pelo tamanho, foi isso que eu quis dizer

Comment: @dvd nesse caso, temos baixa entropia dos bits da senha. O que seria o que o xkcd argumenta contra

Comment: Não vejo razão nenhuma para limitar senhas. Se limitarmos o uso de espaços em branco no final de senhas teríamos que informar isso para o usuário, consequentemente alguém mal intencionado teria uma informação importante sobre como funciona seu sistema de senhas.

Comment: Só lembrando que a validação do lado do cliente, é visível, seja qual for a regra, qualquer um poderá ver os requisitos.

Comment: Eu creio que se for limitar o _subset_ de caracteres, há que se considerar os meios de entrada, e não a "classificação" dos símbolos em si. Por exemplo: Se eu usar o caractere tal, conseguirei fazer login num teclado ou device diferente?

Comment: @Bacco , uma preocupação muito válida de UI. Não havia pensado nisso antes. Creio que o Maniero menciona esse fato na resposta dele

Comment: Posso ter a honra de saber o porquê do negativo? Gostaria de poder melhorar

Comment: Que tal: "Permitir ou não permitir o uso de acentuação em senhas?". Ou então, "Permitir ou não permitir o uso da letra P maiúscula em senhas?". Veja que tanto a sua como essas outras perguntas enveredam mais por discussões técnicas do que de UX. Do ponto de vista do usuário (UX, certo?), nós deveríamos permitir ao usuário colocar o diabo de senha que ele/ela quiser. Afinal, a senha é dele(a) e é ele(a) que vai ter de lembrá-la. :)

Comment: @LuizVieira, no caso de que se sabe, a priori, que é comum que o usuário use como entrada dispositivos distintos dos nossos usuais teclados QWERTY, isso entraria apenas como questão técnica? Não envolveria maior profundidade em UX para as diversas plataformas?

Comment: Certamente envolveria. Mas mesmo os teclados virtuais de dispositivos móveis têm a tecla de espaço, então meu comentário continua válido. Se um dispositivo qualquer não tiver um teclado (físico ou virtual), aí a discussão deveria ser outra: talvez o uso de senhas digitáveis não seja apropriado desde o princípio.

Comment: Aliás, por teclado virtual entende-se um que o usuário consiga digitar nele de forma simulada (tocando a tela, por exemplo). Um teclado virtual em uma TV em que o usuário precisa navegar entre as teclas QWERT usando uma seta é algo totalmente cansativo e ineficiente. Por isso serviços com o Youtube e Netflix tendem a evitar completamente a senha nesses dispositivos (usando, por exemplo, um QRCode para sincronizar com base em outro dispositivo onde é possível e confortável digitar a senha).

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Devolvo a pergunta: que problema vê em considerar espaço em branco?

Eu não vejo problemas técnicos. Talvez de UX. Mas aí é relativo, depende do público.

O espaço é um caractere como outro qualquer, não consigo ver porque ele deva ser tratado diferentemente de `a` ou `1` ou `個`, menos ainda por causa da posição dele. A não ser que a senha seja usada em algum local que não permite este caractere, por exemplo algum controle de entrada ou transmissão de dados de dados que não permita o uso de espaço ou ainda que a senha armazenada seja entrada em outro local.

Alguém pode dizer que a pessoa pode esquecer que tinha espaço ali e aí cria "dor de cabeça" para quem gerencia o sistema por causa disto. É um argumento válido, mas eu acho que deveria permitir qualquer caractere usado tipicamente. Há quem diga que deve ser qualquer Unicode.

Pra mim esses casos que o sistema coloca regra demais é complicado, meça e vá mostrando a força conforme a pessoa vai digitando. Qualquer cálculo de força de senha deve considerar a repetição de um caractere em seguida ou não, como algo de baixa força.

Regras precisam ser informadas e isto baixa a segurança, conforme o Phelipe mencionou em comentário.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score 13):

### Em tese...

Se seu algoritmo de criptografia os aceita, qualquer dado **imprimível** deveria poder fazer parte de uma senha, o resto é política de serviço.

### Definindo uma política de serviço

Você precisa definir uma política de serviço para evitar comportamentos estranhos como:

- trimming de senhas
- aceitar [caracteres de controle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_character) como <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Backspace</kbd> no Windows. Alguns são imprimíveis como esse que citei
- comportamentos automáticos causados por corretores ortográficos ou teclados virtuais como o dos *smartphones*.

#### Senhas: difícil de ser quebrada é diferente de ser difícil de ser lembrada

Para te ajudar a definir sua política, [**leia esse artigo do Jeff Atwood, co-fundador do Stack Overflow, "Password Rules Are Bullshit"**](https://blog.codinghorror.com/password-rules-are-bullshit/). Ele cita os problemas mais comuns das regras que a maioria dos sites adotam e como contorná-los.

[image]

#### Tempo de processamento e uso de CPU

Para definir sua política de serviço, pode usar como argumento o tempo de processamento e uso de CPU, já que criptografar um dado de 100 Kb não deve custar o mesmo do que uma de 3 Mb.

É por esse e outros motivos que alguns serviços limitam a senha em 32 caracteres, por exemplo.

#### Copiar e colar

O que pode prejudicar a usabilidade é o *copy-paste* de senhas, já que com espaços não há como distinguir:

```
Sua senha é <b>darthépaidoluke</b>
Sua senha é <b>darthépaidoluke    </b>
```

Como é que o usuário irá diferenciar esses dois depois de renderizado? Não há como saber onde esse esses espaços terminam.

Esse é outro motivo para não aceitar espaços.

#### O barulho das teclas

Em questão de segurança da informação, há quem diga que o espaço tem um som distinguível no teclado, [(extra!)](https://www.newscientist.com/article/dn7996-keyboard-sounds-reveal-their-words/), por isso não deveria ser aceito ou coisa do tipo. Se o atacante consegue ouvir o som do teclado, fica muito mais fácil quebrar a senha se ele sabe que ela segue o padrão

```
XXX__XX
X: qualquer outro caracetere
_: espaço
```

#### Ok, não quero aceitar espaços nas senhas. E agora?

Você pode mostrar uma mensagem de validação dizendo que não aceita espaços ou fazer o trimming dos espaços (estratégia que o Google usa).

Entendo que não usar espaços pode diminuir o campo amostral de possibilidades de senha, mas permití-los pode fazer com que o usuário digite um espaço sem querer. Isso mesmo! Sem querer. A experiência web mobile é boa, mas não perfeita ainda.

Particularmente, e defendido por UX, eu não gosto da ideia de fazer o trim. Alerte o usuário e peça a correção.

Também [não inclua](https://uxplanet.org/ux-login-register-and-password-the-ultimate-design-guide-f18b1932ee84) 1,000 regras diferentes para criação de uma senha, isso pode prejudicar a usabilidade. Grandes aplicações utilizam em médias 3 *constraints* no máximo.

Como medidor de força, um dos parâmetros pode ser quanto esforço um computador demoraria para quebrar tal senha [(!)](https://howsecureismypassword.net)

Comment: Sobre o som, o atacante (no caso um _eavesdropper_) tenha acesso físico ao local para instalar um equipamento de escuta (ou mesmo estar presente escutando). Não tinha pensado nisso, mas de modo geral, a maior preocupação **creio** que se dê pelo meio virtual. (PS: ótima senha)

Comment: Impressionante o link!

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado se o site de senhas fosse meu, a mensagem seria "Not secure anymore" depois que o usuário revelou :P

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado leia o artigo q anexei ao "definindo a política de serviço" da resposta :)

Comment: Você mudou o link e a imagem de canto, me perdi. Depois eu leio novamente

Comment: excelente resposta!

Answer (score 5):

Vou apenas contribuir com um visão mais focada no lado do usuário e não no lado do desenvolvedor e da validação no banco propriamente.

**Faça um teste primeiro!** Se vc for no `Gmail` por exemple e tentar logar com a sua senha padrão, *mas colocando um espaço em branco no início ou no final da senha* o `Google` vai ignorar esse espaço e aceitar a senha!

**Todas essas opções serão aceitas** `"minhasenha"`, `"  minhasenha"` ou `"minhasenha    "`

Acredito ser muito comum usuários receberem ou salvarem senhas no e-mail ou em um Bloco de Notas que seja. Além disso, em dispositivos Mobile é como o corretor acrescentar algum Espaço em branco principalmente no final das palavras.

Aqui vc pode fazer um teste simples, quando vc **clicar 2x** na senha **(novasenha)**, *vai selecionar junto o espaço em branco que vem após ela*.

> Segue sua nova senha n̲o̲v̲a̲s̲e̲n̲h̲a̲   senhor.

Outro exemplo é quando vc copia e cola a senha e inclui o espaço a frente da palavra, como nesse exemplo simples, que acaba selecionado junto o espaço após os **:**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Então ao meu ver, vc **sim deve permitir os espaços**, seja no início ou no final, *mas considerar esses espaços nas extremidades como parte da validação da senha já é algo a se questionar*...

Pelo visto o Google desconsidera esses espaços e vc pode logar tranquilamente com a **"suasenha       "** no `Gmail`

Answer (score 2):

> Antigamente:

Porque banco de dados usavam ascii, e existia uma problema de conversao entre quebra de linha e espaço, caso tenha visto alguns sites tem uma messagem "nao copie e cole sua senha" para evitar que a quebra de linha apareça...

> Hoje em dia:

O padrao permaneceu, e sim é uma ma pratica. Voce pode usar espaco em branco pq os bancos usam utf8 mas caso seja um sistema antigo que use ascii evite.

Comment: Mas a senha não é salva no banco em aplicações reais, né? Somente ela criptografada, em que na maioria o espaço não é conservado e sim criptografado.

Comment: sim, mas o problema é ler a criptografia e fazer conversao para acsii, que acaba gerando uma diferente string da original @vnbrs

Comment: mas isso é coısa do passado, poucas aplicacoes usao ascii e sao casos bem isolados... por isso nao existe problem em usar espaco em aplicacoes atuais

Answer (score 1):

Realmente não é uma boa **não** permitir espaços em branco nas bordas da senha. Como mencionado na resposta do Maniero, o espaço deve ser tratado com qualquer outro caractere.

Na minha resposta que resultou nesta pergunta, eu mencionei que "*seria interessante também eliminar os espaços nas bordas*". Fiz esta citação levando em conta informação *em geral* vinda de um campo `input`, mas realmente em caso de **senha** não se deve fazer isso (tanto que apaguei tal citação).

Como a senha deverá passar por um algorítimo de hash, ele não tratará os espaços *diferentemente* dos outros caracteres, portanto, não importa se tem ou não espaços *antes*, *depois* ou em ambos.

Ao permitir tais espaços, não vejo isso como uma vantagem, mas até como uma recomendação.