# Quais os tipos de caracteres gerados pela função password_hash()?

Tags: php, segurança, hash, password

A saída que observei após algum dado ser criptografado pela função `password_hash()` está em torno de valores alfanuméricos e alguns caracteres especiais como `$` `.` e `/`.

Existem mais caracteres especiais além desses citados?

Comment: Já leu a [documentação](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.password-hash.php)? Você pode definir qual tipo de hash  que quiser que ele gere, há alguns tipos. Além disso, não importa o formato, importante é ter ciência da validação com o salt.

Comment: Oi Ivan! Li sim! Já solucionado! Valeu, camarada! Estava usando a função de forma incorreta e criei uma dúvida sobre o caso, mas o Maniero deu uma força! Valeu!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dê uma lida na [documentação](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php).

Você está vendo o *salt* ([entenda mais sobre ele](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/2402/101)), esta parte não faz parte do *hash* gerado.

De forma geral não importa o que está sendo gerado. Se o software tem alguma limitação em relação a isto provavelmente ele está errado.

Comment: Na verdade é apenas curiosidade. Pois a função MD5 do php gera apenas saídas Alpha numéricas. Daí a curiosidade na saída password_hash();

Answer (score 2):

O `password_hash()` suporta dois formatos, um para o BCrypt e outro para o Argon2:

- BCrypt: "similar" ao [Modular Crypt Format](http://passlib.readthedocs.io/en/stable/modular_crypt_format.html#overview)
- Argon2: [PHC String Format](https://github.com/P-H-C/phc-string-format/blob/master/phc-sf-spec.md)

---

Em resumo, o PHP usa, para o BCrypt algo bem próximo do MCF:

```
$<algoritmo>$<custo>$<salt><hash>
```

O `<algoritmo>` é o nome do algoritmo e versão, o custo é um valor numérico, do custo computacional escolhido.

O `<salt>` e o `<hash>` podem ter `[a-zA-Z0-9./]`, *que é justamente o base64, trocando o `+` pelo `.`*.

Já o o Argon2 segue uma linha parecida, mas é exatamente o PHC String Format:

```
$<algoritmo>$<parametro-versao>$<parametro-custo>$<salt>$<hash>
```

O `<algoritmo>` pode usar `[a-z0-9-]`. Já a `<parametro-versao>` pode ter um nome usando `[a-z0-9-]` e o seu valor é um hexadecimal, mas pela regra pode usar `[a-zA-Z0-9/+.-]`, ele é divido por um `=`, portanto ele é `v=19`, por exemplo, indicando ser "versão = 1.3".

O `<parametro-custo>` também pode ter um nome de `[a-z0-9-]` e um valor pode ser representado em `[a-zA-Z0-9/+.-]`. Atualmente ele usa os parâmetros de `m`, para memoria, o `t` de tempo, o `p` de paralelismo. Os seus valores são númericos, também dividor por `=`, então algo como `m=1024,t=2,p=2`.

O `<salt>` e o `<hash>` são representados por `[a-zA-Z0-9/+.-]`.

---

**Por fim, ele usa `a-z`, `A-Z`, `0-9`, `/`, `.`, `-`, `+`, `$`, `=`.**

Comment: Valeu, Inkeliz! Muito obrigado!