# Caminho inverso hash_hmac

Tags: php, hash

É possivel fazer o caminho inverso da seguinte função?

```
hash_hmac('sha512', $password . $user_salt, $this->salt)
```

Estou a recuperar usuário de uma aplicação para um nova e preciso recuperar as senhas para cadastrar na criptografia que uso.
Já procurei na net, e não encontrei nada concreto.

Comment: Precisa ver se a "criptografia nova que você usa" é boa, antes de mais nada (nada caseiro, exceto se você fizer parte de uma exímia equipe de criptógrafos) - Mencionei isso, pq como você falou em caminho inverso, espero que a sua solução não o tenha.

Comment: Creio que essa leitura pode interessar: [Como fazer hash de senhas de forma segura](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/2402/70)

Comment: Na verdade a que vou usar e a função crypt() do php e um salt que vem de um server no EUA quando vai criar o usuario. Não posso mudar o método de criptografia. Nunca usei dessa maneira.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Não, ao menos ela foi feita justamente para que não consiga reverter. Porém, o HMAC não é destinado a senha, então a única forma que temos para recuperar o valor pode ser um pouco mais rápido.

O HMAC é uma Keyed Hash, ela pode ser utilizada para autenticação de mensagens (MAC) e também pode ser usada para deviração de chaves (KDF). *O seu uso não é nenhum dos dois, já que está usando uma senha, e não uma chave, para esse fim existe o PBKDF2, que pode usar HMAC internamente.*

---

A única forma de *reverter* este valor é justamente uma busca exaustiva, tentar todas as tentativas possíveis, isso pode ser feito usando [Hashcat](https://hashcat.net/hashcat/). Porém isso não é tão rápido, principalmente se houver muitas senhas, usando 8x GTX 1080 Ti isso irá fazer 4.300.000 tentativas por segundo, em média.

---

Mas se o seu intuito é "cadastrar na criptografia que uso", você pode simplesmente cadastrar a hash e sinalizar que aquele usuário está usando uma senha antiga.

Por exemplo, se você usa o `hash_hmac` e agora quer mudar para `argon2id`, você tem atualmente algo como:

```
Usuario | Senha     | Salt
Inkeliz   0x00..00   0xFF...FF
```

Então basta fazer a hash da hash:

```
Senha = argon2i(senha = 0x00..00, salt = 0xAF...AF)
```

Então, supondo que `Senha` retornou `0xAA...AA` basta usa-la e criar uma sinalização:

```
Usuario | Senha     | Salt      | SaltAntigo
Inkeliz   0xAA..AA   0xAF...AF   0xFF...FF
```

O `SaltAntigo` poderia ser boolean (true/false), por exemplo `EstaUsandoSenhaAntiga?`. Mas, podemos também usa-lo para guardar o salt antigo, se ele for nulo indicará que não usa o antigo. Se você pretende manter o mesmo salt então poderia usar um boolean mesmo. ;)

Então se outro usuário se cadastrar recentemente:

```
Usuario | Senha     | Salt      | SaltAntigo
Inkeliz   0xAA..AA   0xAF...AF   0xFF...FF
Novo      0xAB..AB   0xBF...BF   null
```

Dessa forma, por exemplo:

```
$senha = $_POST['senha'];

if $salt_antigo !== null {
    $senha = hmac($senha, $salt_antigo)
} 

$senha = argon2id($senha, $salt)
//...

// Se tudo estiver certo e temos a senha dele,
// podemos atualizar para usar diretamente o novo algorítimo:

$nova_senha = argon2id($_POST['senha'], $novo_salt)
query("UPDATE contas SET Senha = $nova_senha, Salt = $novo_salt, SaltAntigo = null")
```

Dessa forma todos usam o novo algorítimo, aqueles que usam o antigo vão atualizando para o novo, na medida que vão entrando no site. ;)

Comment: Então tem quase 3000 usuários. Preciso passa para minha aplicação. Mais acho que vou verificar se usa um cadastro antigo, se sim loga com esse método, senão loga com a minha criptografia.

Comment: E na outra aplicação que tenho que importar ta com 12104 usuários com a mesma forma de hashear. Na importação da aplicação no EUA os programadores la resolveram resetar a senha de todo mundo e obrigar a redefinição, mais acho que o transtorno e grande.

Comment: Essa solução do renovar no login é uma das mais "suaves", e não incomoda o usuário. O que você pode fazer é especificar um prazo, e mandar um aviso depois de um tempo pros que não logaram ainda acessarem o sistema.

Comment: Cara. Não tinha reparado direito sua resposta. Mais era em parte o que tava pensando em fazer. Mais não tinha imaginado trocar a codificação já que sabia a senha correta. Realmente da certo mesmo. Obrigado.