# Qual a criptografia de senha devo utilizar com Node.js? qual mais segura?

Tags: node.js, criptografia, senhas

estou fazendo um curso de node.js e neste o tutor utiliza md5 para criptografar a senha.. mais li em alguns artigos que md5 ñ é muito seguro.. qual a mais recomendada para utilizar com Node.js?

Obrigado!

Comment: Acredito que a linguagem não interfere na criptografia a ser usada, de uma olhada [nessa pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/2402/como-fazer-hash-de-senhas-de-forma-segura)

Answer (score 6):

Um bom *package* para esse tipo de ação é o `bcrypt`, que gera senhas usando `salt`.

- https://www.npmjs.com/package/bcryptjs

O funcionamento é simples. Irei demonstrar usando as versões síncronas a seguir.

```
const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');

const password = '123';

const salt = bcrypt.genSaltSync(10);
const hash = bcrypt.hashSync(password, salt);

// Guarde o `hash` na sua base de dados...
```

Para verificar (comparar) os hashes, use:

```
// Assumindo que `db_password` seja o hash encriptado no exemplo anterior:

const db_password = db.password; // Imagine que veio da base de dados.

bcrypt.compareSync('123', db_password); // Irá retornar true.
bcrypt.compareSync('456', db_password); // Irá retornar false.
```

Para saber mais e entender melhor o funcionamento, sugiro que dê uma olhada no README do repositório no GitHub:

- https://github.com/dcodeIO/bcrypt.js

Comment: +1 para usar `bcrypt` e `salt`. Já utilizei `bcrypt` não só para criptografar a senha, como todas as informações sensíveis dos usuários (nome, telefone, etc.) e mensagens trocadas por chat.

Comment: Sobre o comentário acima, o bcrypt não deve ser usado para criptografar nome, telefone muito menos mensagens de chat. Ele é um HASHING de uma via só, ou seja, a única forma de encontrar o valor criptografado é "chutando" o valor de entrada, assim como no password. Fora isso, ele é um algoritmo custoso se comparado com os algoritmos de criptografia.