# A função HASHBYTES() do SQLServer é criptograficamente seguro?

Tags: sql-server, criptografia, hash

A empresa que trabalho hoje ela tem muito da programação feita no banco de dados por meio de *procedures* e estava vendo como era feita a criação do *hash* das senhas e da persistência das mesmas no banco. Descobri que foi feito a utilização de uma função bem antiga chamado `PWDENCRYPT()`. Estou querendo sugerir uma modificação nessa criptografia e pesquisando, descobri essa `HASHBYTES()` que é uma função nativa do próprio SQL Server que faz isso conforme é informado o algoritmo de *hash*. Gostaria de saber se ele é criptograficamente seguro e pode ser usado em produção.

Comment: Nada é seguro. O que era seguro ontem hoje já não o é mais. É tudo questão de tempo.

Comment: Nenhum dos dois foi feita para senhas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sim, é segura se usar o algoritmo certo, se usar *salt*, etc., use um SHA2, não use MD e evite os SHA anteriores.

Se quiser saber mais: [Como fazer hash de senhas de forma segura?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/2402/101).

[Documentação](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/hashbytes-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15/?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397).

Comment: Mesmo sem usar Salt e sem as iterações para tornar o hash mais lento?

Comment: O Salt sempre é bom, por isso passei o *link* para aprender mais como usar.