# Como selecionar e validar senha criptografada em PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Olá, gostaria de saber qual a melhor maneira de selecionar e verificar a senha hash(senha) em um banco de dados e comparar com a senha inserida pelo usuário em um formulário de login. É mais adequado armazenar no BD o salt ?
No exemplo abaixo eu criei o hash da senha antes de selecionar no banco:

```
<?php

include('conf.php');

$email = 'lala@123.com';
$senha = 'lala.123';
$custo = '08';
$salt = 'Cf1f11ePArKlBJomM0F6aJ';

$hash = crypt($senha, '$2a$' . $custo . '$' . $salt . '$');

    $query_select = "SELECT email, password FROM usuarios WHERE email = '$email' AND password = '$hash'";
    $select = mysqli_query($conexao,$query_select);

    if (mysqli_num_rows($select) == 1) {
        echo "Login Permitido";
    }
    else {
        echo "Login ou senha invalidos";
    } ?>
```

Já neste exemplo eu selecionei o hash no banco para depois comparar com a senha inserida no formulário utilizando o password_verify():

```
<?php 

#----------------- INCLUDING FILE --> "conf.php"
include('conf.php');

    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {


        $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($conexao, $_POST['email']);
        $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($conexao, $_POST['password']);


        $query_select_email = "SELECT email FROM usuarios WHERE email = '$email'";
        $select_email = mysqli_query($conexao,$query_select_email);

        $query_select_password = "SELECT password FROM usuarios";
        $select_password = mysqli_query($conexao,$query_select_password);

        while($array = mysqli_fetch_array($select_password)) {
        $logarray = $array['password'];


            if (password_verify($password, $logarray) && mysqli_num_rows($select_email) == 1) {
                echo "Login permitido";

            }
        }
    } ?>
```

Aceito qualquer dica relacionado a segurança e para melhorar o código, desde já agradeço.

Answer (score 0):

O `salt` deve ser único para cada senha, fazer `$salt = 'Cf1f11ePArKlBJomM0F6aJ';` é um tanto inutil, isto deixaria de ser um [`salt`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_(cryptography)) e passaria a ser um [`pepper`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pepper_(cryptography)).

Então, respondendo a primeira pergunta:

> É mais adequado armazenar no BD o salt ?

Sim. Não é só mais adequado... Isto é a própria definição de *salt*, já que ele requer que seja único por senha, isso é: para cada senha um salt diferente. Por consequência seria conveniente armazenar o *salt* em algum lugar que possua referencia com a hash da senha, o banco de dados seria o local mais adequado neste caso.

---

> Já neste exemplo eu selecionei o hash no banco para depois comparar com a senha inserida no formulário utilizando o password_verify()

O `password_hash` e `password_verify` é o recomendado, ele já armazena o algorítimo usado, o salt, e a dificuldade na própria hash. Por causa disso, basta que armazene a hash no banco de dados e ela contrám as informações necessárias para recalcular hash, usando o mesmo algoritmo, dificuldade e salt. Além disso, ele gera internamente um salt.

[Você pode ver mais sobre isso aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/2402/como-fazer-hash-de-senhas-de-forma-segura/259596#259596).

Eu recomendo que troque o BCrypt para Argon2id, para isso use o `PASSWORD_ARGON2ID`:

```
password_hash($senha, PASSWORD_ARGON2ID)
```

Note, que o algortimo só é definido no momento da criação da hash e não na comparação, portanto você pode altera-lo sem quebrar a compatibilidades com as hashes já armazenadas, e para atualizar os algoritmos das senhas pode usar o `passwod_needs_rehash`, na medida que os usuários forem fazendo login.

O `password_hash` tem um problema, que é sua dificuldade baixa. Por padrão, o PHP, como smepre, define uma dificuldade extremamente baixa, você deve ajustar até que fique confortável (quanto mais alto melhor, porém há chances de DoS e piora a experiencia do usuário). Para ajustar defina:

```
password_hash($senha, PASSWORD_ARGON2ID, ['memory_cost' => 1<<17, 'time_cost' => 5, 'threads' => 2];
```

Altere o custo de memoria, o custo de iteração e o número de threads, e faça um teste de quanto tempo é capaz de esperar o processo.

O [custo padrão é de](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/argon2_password_hash):

```
memory_cost = 1024 KiB
time_cost = 2
threads = 2
```

*O Argon2id e o BCrypt possuem ajustes diferentes de dificuldade.*

---