# Proteção De Senhas No PHP

Tags: php, criptografia, php-7, hash

Tenho uma função implementada em meu sistema que faz o armazenamento da senha da seguinte forma:

```
function codifica($usuario, $senha){
    $codifica = crypt($senha,$usuario);
    $codifica = hash('sha512',$codifica);
    return $codifica;
}
```

Tenho visto que geralmente o pessoal faz simplesmente o uso do [password_hash](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.password-hash.php) e do [password_verify](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.password-verify.php)

Não entendo muito de criptografias e hashs, gostaria de saber se a função que utilizei é suficientemente segura ou se devo parar tudo que estou fazendo e implementar o password_hash() e password_verify().

Comment: Isto responde à sua pergunta? [Como fazer hash de senhas de forma segura?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/2402/como-fazer-hash-de-senhas-de-forma-segura)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pelo que eu entendi, resumidamente:

A função que uso está relativamente segura, porém o password_hash implementa e elevava a segurança gerando salts aleatórias. A função mencionada gera uma espécie de salt usando o crypt() do usuário e senha, ou seja, um salt fixo que pode ser atacado usando rainbow tables (tabelas de consulta reversa para hashes).

Para quem quiser saber mais, segue o link da fonte em português:
https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/br/library/wa-php-renewed_2/index.html