# Criptografas senha com crypto no node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, criptografia

Bom tenho uma aplicação que precisa de uma criptografia na senha, estou utilizando `crypto` do `node js` pra fazer a criptografia, porém consigo fazer a criptografia mas não consigo descriptografar pra depois conseguir autenticar o usuário. Consegue fazer dessa forma para fazer a criptografia.

```
const crypto = require('crypto');

module.exports = function encryptedPwd(pwd){
    const iv = crypto.randomBytes(16).toString('hex').slice(0, 16);
    const key = crypto.createHash('sha256').update(String(pwd)).digest('base64').substr(0, 32);//pwd.toString().substr(0, 32);
    const cipher = crypto.createCipheriv('aes-256-ctr', key, iv);
    let encrypted = cipher.update(String(pwd), 'utf8', 'hex') + cipher.final('hex');
    return encrypted;
}
```

Porém a senha tem que ser do tamanho de 32 caracteres(não queria que fosse assim) e também não consigo descriptografar. Para descriptografar fiz o seguinte trecho

```
    const testes1 = value => {
      const iv = crypto.randomBytes(16).toString('hex').slice(0, 16);
      const key = value.substr(0, 32);
      const cipher = crypto.createDecipheriv('aes-256-ctr', key, iv);
      let encrypted = cipher.update(String(value), 'hex', 'utf8') + cipher.final('hex');
      return encrypted;
    }
```

Mas ocorre o seguinte erro

```
    internal/assert.js:14
    throw new ERR_INTERNAL_ASSERTION(message);
    ^

Error [ERR_INTERNAL_ASSERTION]: Cannot change encoding
This is caused by either a bug in Node.js or incorrect usage of Node.js internals.
Please open an issue with this stack trace at https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues

    at assert (internal/assert.js:14:11)
    at getDecoder (internal/crypto/cipher.js:82:3)
    at Decipheriv.final (internal/crypto/cipher.js:175:21)
    at testes1 (E:\projetos\quadraTenis\backend\src\server.js:10:74)
    at Object.<anonymous> (E:\projetos\quadraTenis\backend\src\server.js:13:13)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1137:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1157:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:985:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:878:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:71:12) {
  code: 'ERR_INTERNAL_ASSERTION'
}
```

Comment: Falando sobre criptografias em geral... Você não faz a descriptografia, você criptografa a senha que o usuário enviou com os mesmos dados (geralmente uma chave privada fixa e um salt aleatório que também é salvo com a senha) e compara o resultado com a senha salva. Não parece que é isso que esteja fazendo, mas não conheço a biblioteca então não posso afirmar

Comment: Criptografar algo não é a forma mais segura de se "salvar" uma senha. É até desconsiderado como uma opção para autenticar uma senha. **Não confunda criptografia com um _hash_ (seguro para esse fim).** Para saber mais, leia [Como fazer hash de senhas de forma segura?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/2402/como-fazer-hash-de-senhas-de-forma-segura)

Answer (score -2):

Senhas não devem ser criptografadas, mas embaralhadas com um algoritmo de hash (veja mais detalhes [nessa resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/2405/165800)). Quando você usa a função [`createHash`](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_crypto_createhash_algorithm_options) utilizando o algoritmo [`SHA-256`](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-2), você está criando um [hash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function), portanto, não há como reverter e obter o valor original.

Você deve salvar o hash que foi gerado sobre a senha do usuário que está sendo criado. Para autenticar o usuário, você precisa aplicar o mesmo algoritmo de hash na senha enviada na requisição, a fim de comparar esse hash com o que foi salvo no banco de dados.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Eu não estou entendendo por que estão votando negativo em minha resposta. Ela responde a pergunta e ainda esclarece melhor o porquê de se usar hash.

Comment: Não foi eu que dei negativo, mas SHA-256 não é feito para senhas. Além disso, o SHA-256 não possui nonce/salt, portanto usuários com mesma senha teriam a mesma hash: logo uma busca-exaustiva/brute-force, iria quebrar a senha de vários usuários num único golpe, somado ao fato do custo computacional ser muito mais baixo do que um Argon2/BCrypt bem configurado. Você tem o PBKDF2, designado para senhas e que, pode, usar o HMAC-SHA-256. Entretanto, há opções melhores, e feitas para senhas, como o Argon2 (que é o vencedor do PHC, https://password-hashing.net).

Comment: Obrigado por esclarecer.