# Onde eu devo armazenar o Salt de um hash de senha?

Tags: hash, password, cracker

Seguindo os bons princípios de segurança, compreendo que é necessário armazenar o Hash de uma senha ao invés de a propria senha em plain text, porém o problema é que de fato o hash sempre é o mesmo e isso pode ser explorado por ataques como **rainbow table**. Para mitigar isso, no meu entendimento, foi criada a ideia do Salt então, que seria uma sequência de bits aleatórios que são adicionados ao hash da senha. Deste modo, portanto, cada usuário teria um hash diferente, mesmo que dois usuários tenham a mesma senha. Ficando, compreendo, da seguinte maneira em base de dados:

| USER | HASH_SENHA | SALT | RESULTADO |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| VICTOR | abcde12345 | 238827391 | abcde12345238827391 |
| KAIO | abcde12345 | 362736187 | abcde123453627361871 |

Mas eu vou armazenar o SALT e o HASH no mesmo database, certo?
Logo, não basta o atacante simplesmente realizar o mesmo ataque mas considerando os salts?
Por exemplo: Ao invés de o atacante considerar o HASH apenas da senha, ele faz o HASH da senha + o salt e pronto.

Eu compreendo que os hashes ficam diferentes e isso é excelente para atrapalhar a vida dos malvados, mas não basta apenas o hacker realizar o mesmo ataque mas considerando o salt? afinal de contas, ele já está na base mesmo.

Comment: Isso foi tratado em [Como fazer hash de senhas de forma segura?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/2402/70) - Salt é para evitar que se usem hashes pré calculados, obrigando a usar força bruta em lugares que bastaria um ataque com rainbow tables ou similar, e evita análise lotes de senhas de uma vez só. Na resposta que postei, o salt é explicado no parágrafo iniciado por: _Salts: uma das vantagens do atacante é o paralelismo. O atacante pega um monte de senha ..._ (leia o parágrafo todo para entender a finalidade dele). Pode guardar onde for mais útil, usualmente junto do hash por praticidade.

Comment: E sobre sua dúvida, ainda na resposta que mencionei, é detalhada em _**O salt não foi feito pra ser secreto**, senão seria chamado de chave. Você não precisa divulgar o salt, mas se precisar (usando uma solução de hash no cliente, por exemplo), não se preocupe. O salt existe apenas para ser único. Não é nada mais do que a seleção de uma função de hash entre muitas._

Comment: Detalhe, você está aplicando errado o salt, por isso aparenta não fazer sentido. **Não é para concatenar salt no hash**, e sim na senha. `senha` vira `senha238827391`, ai faz o hash e guarda o `238827391` como salt, e hash `a708f376fc492abe6128fdbef07f245e`, e no segundo exemplo `senha` vira `senha362736187`, e o hash fica `e15c87baa4071645a10b5f1ffa089cd5`. Note que concatenação e MD5 é só exemplo, há maneiras melhores de usar salt com derivação ou vetor na geração do hash. O importante é que funcione só na geração, não no caminho inverso. [Exemplo básico - IDEONE](https://ideone.com/TlaMIk)

Comment: uma explicação mais visual (em ingles) pode ser vista nesta postagem de [blog](https://blog.bytebytego.com/p/how-does-https-work-episode-6#%C2%A7how-to-store-passwords-safely-in-the-database-and-how-to-validate-a-password)

Comment: @Bacco
Mas mesmo que o hash vá para a senha, tudo bem, mas se o cracker tiver acesso ao salt não basta ele simplesmente somar cada tentativa da wordlist com o salt?
Ex:
SALT: 12345;
SENHA DO USUARIO: BANANA;
SALVO NO BANCO = HASH(BANANA12345);

Cracker pega a wordlist e
HASH(TOMATE12345);
HASH(CEBOLA12345);
[..]
HASH(BANANA12345) -> DEU CERTO;

Não é isso?

Comment: Sim. É para isso o salt, para que ele tenha que testar uma por uma. Sem o salt ele pega um DB de hashes prontos e localiza facilmente uma senha SEM TESTAR (só comparando com hashes existentes). Com salt ele é obrigado a refazer todos os hashes do DB, uma por uma. E mesmo que tenha  10 senhas iguais, ainda assim vai ter que quebrar uma por uma. Lembrando que hash de senha não é pegar um SHA ou MD5, hash bom para senha é demorado. Mas isso está explicado naquele link, vale uma boa lida.

Comment: @Bacco
Agora faz sentido.. é só pra 'atrasar' a vida do cracker, né?
Eu sempre imaginei que, num cenário ideal, o salt deveria ficar em outra base para que o cracker passasse mais sufoco. Mas agora entendi o conceito, o segredo é não permitir que o cracker simplesmente pegue uma wordlist de hasehs já prontos, e não dá senha como um todo.. ai ele compara o database inteiro com os hashes já conhecidos.. Faz sentido

Comment: Pode ter isso que disse, mas não chama mais salt (tem um exemplo com "pepper" lá no link). O salt é para evitar ataques de dicionário, senhas repetidas etc. Dicionário é  tipo uma coleção de senhas que já foi hasheada antes. Sem salt basta vc pesquisar o hash se tem nesse dicionário. Com salt, o dicionário passa a ser inútil, tem que ver uma por uma.

Comment: Tudo é apenas para atrasar… inclusive o algoritmo de derivação (como Argon2, Bcrypt…), eles possuem parâmetros para ajustar o custo (memória e iteração necessaria). O salt é apenas pra que ele tenha que pagar este preço para cada senha (já que o salt faz as senhas iguais serem diferentes).